# How can I get the size of a memory block allocated using malloc()?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [How can I get the size of an array from a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c)
> [Is there any way to determine the size of a C++ array programmatically?  And if not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-n)

I get a pointer to a chunk of allocated memory out of a C style function.
Now, it would be really interesting for debugging purposes to know how
big the allocated memory block that this pointer points is.

Is there anything more elegant than provoking an exception by blindly running over its boundaries?

Thanks in advance,
Andreas

#### EDIT:

I use VC++2005 on Windows, and GCC 4.3 on Linux

#### EDIT2:

I have `_msize` under VC++2005
Unfortunately it results in an exception in debug mode....

#### EDIT3:

Well. I have tried the way I described above with the exception, and it works.
At least while I am debugging and ensuring that immediately after the call
to the library exits I run over the buffer boundaries. Works like a charm.

It just isn't elegant and in no way usable in production code.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-n

and:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/array-size-from-pointer-in-c

Comment: There were no useful answers there.

Comment: @AndreasT: can you elaborate on that? What are you looking for that isn't answered on one or the other of those questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/array-size-from-pointer-in-c seems especially close to what you're asking here). Right now, this seems like a duplicate - if you could clarify what you're looking to do, perhaps we could identify answers that better match...

Comment: On the site you mentioned, which the search didn't propose to me, it is answer number three, not the accepted one, that provides this information:
msize() or similar functions (_msize() etc).
I was not searching for the size of arrays, I want to know how much memory in bytes was allocated at a given position. This is of course more or less the same problem, since especially in C you allocate arrays and large memory blocks the same way. But I don't need to know about arrays which might have some size information attached. I needed the size of an allocated mem block.

Comment: The similarity in C was not obvious to me.

Comment: @AndreasT - As thirtythreeforty  mentioned here, see the following answer (for a similar question):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281720/1971003

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not standard but if your library has a `msize()` function that will give you the size.

A common solution is to wrap `malloc` with your own function that logs each request along with the size and resulting memory range, in the release build you can switch back to the 'real' `malloc`.

Comment: +1 I did this years ago. It's trivial to implement and very useful

Comment: I have no access to the source.

Comment: But the _msize tip might wirk. Thanks!

Comment: Check for a _debug_malloc package. There might be a runtime library to get the malloc information at least in a debug build. In general though you shouldn't design your code assuming this is possible

Comment: You can also use the `malloc_usable_size()` function, which is provided on GNU platforms.

Comment: What library that has `msize()` ?

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind sleazy violence for the sake of debugging, you can #define macros to hook calls to malloc and free and pad the first 4 bytes with the size.

To the tune of

```
void *malloc_hook(size_t size) {
    size += sizeof (size_t);
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    *(size_t *) ptr = size;
    return ((size_t *) ptr) + 1;
}

void free_hook (void *ptr) {
    ptr = (void *) (((size_t *) ptr) - 1);
    free(ptr);
}

size_t report_size(ptr) {
    return * (((size_t *) ptr) - 1);
}
```

then

```
#define malloc(x) malloc_hook(x)
```

and so on

Comment: Aside from alignment issues, this is actually the best way to do it in a portable manner.  If you use something more adventurous like dlmalloc you could take advantage of weak linking, but for a PC app this is probably overkill.

Comment: This sounds good too, but I don't have access to the code.

Comment: Since I unknowingly answered a duplicate question with an almost identical solution, it must deserve an up-vote!

Comment: This did not work as written, there seem to be a few problems, but I got it to work. Nice hack!

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish could you post the code ?

Answer (score 10):

The C runtime library does not provide such a function. Furthermore, deliberately provoking an exception will not tell you how big the block is either.

Usually the way this problem is solved in C is to maintain a separate variable which keeps track of the size of the allocated block. Of course, this is sometimes inconvenient but there's generally no other way to know.

Your C runtime library *may* provide some heap debug functions that can query allocated blocks (after all, `free()` needs to know how big the block is), but any of this sort of thing will be nonportable.

Answer (score 6):

With `gcc` and the `GNU linker`, you can easily wrap `malloc`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void* __real_malloc(size_t sz);
void* __wrap_malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = __real_malloc(sz);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc of size %d yields pointer %p\n", sz, ptr);

    /* if you wish to save the pointer and the size to a data structure, 
       then remember to add wrap code for calloc, realloc and free */

    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    char *x;
    x = malloc(103);

    return 0;
}
```

and compile with

```
gcc a.c -o a -Wall -Werror -Wl,--wrap=malloc
```

(Of course, this will also work with c++ code compiled with g++, and with the new operator (through it's mangled name) if you wish.)

In effect, the statically/dynamically loaded library will also use your `__wrap_malloc`.

Comment: Really? How is that possible? Will code from some .a or .so file that has no debug info be overwritten by that?  If yes: Cool! B)

Comment: Weak references.  The linker will override the symbol references to malloc for you and point them to the place you specify.

Comment: Yup, no debugging info needed, any library contains a symbol table for the symbols it provides and for the symbols it needs to get from elsewhere. So you can tell the linker what function to bind with the malloc symbol of your executable.

Answer (score 4):

No, and you can't rely on an exception when overrunning its boundaries, unless it's in your implementation's documentation.  It's part of the stuff you really don't need to know about to write programs.  Dig into your compiler's documentation or source code if you really want to know.

Comment: Any particular reason why this was downvoted?

Comment: Not downvoted by me, but possibly because malloc and access to malloc'd memory is not known for throwing exceptions, being part of C.

Comment: Well it does. And I can request that memory chunk and then go provoke the access violation and it simply works. I do this in c++ as the tag states, so exceptions are thrown.

Comment: On Windows, you *might* get a structured exception (Access Violation), since that's how the OS communicates that you've stepped over the line. On Linux, i think the equivalent is a segmentation fault. Whether or not your runtime converts these to C++ exceptions is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It's also iffy.  As you say, on Windows you might get an access violation, and on Linux you might get a segmentation fault.  Without actually knowing, I'd suspect that these were caused by the virtual memory manager, and therefore would indicate leaving memory pages rather than allocated memory areas.

Comment: @David: right - you could potentially end up in another portion of allocated memory, silently trashing other data-structures (including those used by the memory manager...) or reading bogus data. Dangerous territory...

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard C function to do this. Depending on your platform, there may be a non-portable method - what OS and C library are you using?

Note that provoking an exception is unreliable - there may be other allocations immediately after the chunk you have, and so you might not get an exception until long after you exceed the limits of your current chunk.

Answer (score 4):

Memory checkers like [Valgrind's memcheck](http://valgrind.org/) and [Google's TCMalloc](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) (the heap checker part) keep track of this sort of thing.

You can use TCMalloc to dump a heap profile that shows where things got allocated, or you can just have it check to make sure your heap is the same at two points in program execution using [SameHeap()](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heap_checker.html).

Comment: I will definately check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution: on Windows you can use the **PageHeap** to catch a memory access outside the allocated block.

PageHeap is an alternate memory manager present in the Windows kernel (in the NT varieties but nobody should be using any other version nowadays). It takes every allocation in a process and returns a memory block that has its end aligned with the end of a memory page, then it makes the following page unaccessible (no read, no write access). If the program tries to read or write past the end of the block, you'll get an access violation you can catch with your favorite debugger.

How to get it: Download and install the package Debugging Tools for Windows from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

then launch the GFlags utility, go to the 3rd tab and enter the name of your executable, then Hit the  key. Check the PageHeap checkbox, click OK and you're good to go.

The last thing: when you're done with debugging, don't ever forget to launch GFlags again, and disable PageHeap for the application. GFlags enters this setting into the Registry (under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\), so it is persistent, even across reboots.

Also, be aware that using PageHeap can increase the memory needs of your application tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do what you want is to *BE* the allocator.  If you filter all requests, and then record them for debugging purposes, then you can find out what you want when the memory is free'd.

Additionally, you can check at the end of the program to see if all allocated blocks were freed, and if not, list them.  An ambitious library of this sort could even take **FUNCTION** and **LINE** parameters via a macro to let you know exactly where you are leaking memory.

Finally, Microsoft's MSVCRT provides a a debuggable heap that has many useful tools that you can use in your debug version to find memory problems: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bebs9zyz.aspx

On Linux, you can use valgrind to find many errors. http://valgrind.org/

Comment: It is not me that allocates the mem, it is a library that I have no source access to.