# Length of an `int` array in Objective C

Tags: arrays, c, objective-c

I am passing an Integer array to a function.
Next I want to traverse through the array.
In C and C++ this worked by simply using `arrayname.length` which gave the number of elements in array.  What is the way to find that in Objective-C?

`[NSArrayObject length]` works for `NSArray` type but I want it for `int[]`.  Not even `[XYZ count]` works (an already suggested answer) so I'm looking for another way here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There isn't anything specific to Objective-C with an array of ints. You would use the same technique as if you were using C.

```
sz = (sizeof foo) / (sizeof foo[0]);
```

Comment: I tried this...i saw dis for a 2-dimension array but my array is single dimension...like just int foo[] so wen i do sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]) it returns 4/4 i.e.  1
..i have already tried it...but no luck..is there any other way?
Thanks

Comment: @Darpan: This works only when you declare int foo[5], not int foo[].

Comment: agree w/ mouviciel, this won't get what you want.

Comment: i have experimented on this. the correct way to display int foo[] length is use sizeof (foo)/4 . need to divide by 4. it works also to not primitive (NSString).

Answer (score 31):

You can use [XYZ count] to get the length of the array

Comment: The question is about C array, where there is no count selector.

Answer (score 21):

There is no such thing as `array.length` in C. An int array in Objective-C is **exactly the same** as an int array in C. If it's statically defined like `int foo[5]`, then you can do `sizeof(foo)` to get the size — but only in the same function `foo` is defined in (to other functions, it's just an int pointer, not an array per se). Otherwise, there is no inherent way to get this information. You need to either pass the size around or use sentinel values (like the terminating '\0' in C strings, which are just arrays of char).

Comment: I am looking for length i.e. number of elements in an integer array.
and not sizeof.as wen id o sizeof it simply returns me the sizeof int

Comment: As I said, no can do. `sizeof()` works for statically sized arrays like the example I gave above in the same function they are defined in. That's the closest C comes to supporting this.

Answer (score 8):

[array count] this appears to work the easiest in objective-c

Answer (score 6):

Huh? In C, there's no such thing as "arrayname.length". An array of a primitive type, such as `int[]`, does not have any length information associated with it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

this code can be use when the total number of element in array are not known.

```
main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    int i;
    clrscr();
    for (i=0;i<=((sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));i++)
    {
        puts(a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: 4 spaces before a line of text tells the site to use code formatting. To quickly put 4 spaces before many lines of code, select all of the lines and click the **{}** button. I fixed it for you, to make it readable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `arrayname.length` in C. That is why so many functions take argument pairs, one argument with the array and one argument with the length of the array. The most obvious case for this is the main function. You can find this function is all your iPhone projects in a file named `main.m`, it will look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
  [pool release];
  return retVal;
}
```

Notice how the `argv` agument is a **v**ector, or array of strings, and the `argc` argument is a **c**ount of how many items that are in this array.

You will have to do the same thing for all primitive types, this is the *C* part of Objective-C. If you stay in the *Objective* parts using NSArray or subclasses works fine, but requires all elements to be objects.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a job for `NSMutableArray`.  is there a reason why you need to work with a C array?  if not, consider `NSMutableArray`.

i may be wrong (so please correct me if i am), but there's no easy way in C to get the size of int[] at runtime.  you would have to do something like create a struct to hold your array and an int where you can keep track of how many items in your array yourself.

even fancier, you can make your struct hold your array and a block.  then you can design the block to do the tracking for you.

but this is more a C question, not an objective-c quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of integers, wrap them in NSNumber objects and place them into an NSArray.

What you are asking to do, is not really supported well in C though there is a method on the mac you could try (malloc_size):

[determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

**You should try the following approach:**

```
float ptArray[] = {97.8, 92.3, 89.4, 85.7, 81.0, 73.4, 53.0, 42.3, 29.4, 14.1};

int x = sizeof(ptArray)/sizeof(ptArray[0]);

 NSLog(@"array count = %d", x);
```

**Output**:

```
array count = 10
```

Comment: In addition to posting some code, it's helpful to include a description of what is going on.