# Size of an NSArray

Tags: arrays, objective-c

How do you get the size of an `NSArray` and print it in the console using `NSLog`?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count

Answer (score 89):

```
int size = [array count];
NSLog(@"there are %d objects in the array", size);
```

Comment: Technically it should be `NSUInteger size = ...`, but +1 anyway.  :)

Comment: You'll have to cast it to a type supported by printf anyway to print it, because printf doesn't have a format specifier for NS[U]Integer.

Comment: @Chuck the docs say to use `%ld` and `%lu` for `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger`, respectively.  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5

Comment: @Chuck which technically is a cast to a `long` and `unsigned long`, but it's what recommended :)

Answer (score 12):

An answer to another answer:

You can't get the size of the array in megabytes, at least not without doing some tricky, unsupported* C voodoo. `NSArray` is a class cluster, which means we don't know how it's implemented internally.  Indeed, the implementation used can [change depending on how many items are in the array](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/). Moreover, the size of the array is disjoint from the size of the objects the array references, since those objects live elsewhere on the heap. Even the structure that holds the object pointers isn't technically "part" of the array, since it isn't necessarily `calloc`'d right next to the actual `NSArray` on the heap.

If you want the size of the array struct itself, well that's apparently only 4 bytes:

```
NSLog(@"Size: %d", sizeof(NSArray));
```

Prints:

```
2010-03-24 20:08:33.334 EmptyFoundation[90062:a0f] Size: 4
```

(Granted, that's not a decent representation, since `NSArray` is probably just an abstract interface for another kind of object, usually something like an `NSCFArray`.  If you look in `NSArray.h`, you'll see that an `NSArray` has no instance variables.  Pretty weird for something that's supposed to hold other objects, eh?)

`*` By "unsupported" I mean "not recommended", "delving into the inner mysticism of class clusters", and "undocumented and private API, if it even exists"

Answer (score 6):

Size can be determined by sending 'count' to the NSArray instance, and printing to console can be done via NSLog(), eg:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSLog(@"array size is %d", [array count]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post for your array size question

[Length of an Array in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530050/length-of-an-array-in-objective-c)

Use NSLog to write to the console...

```
NSLog(@"The array size is %@", arraySize);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4

let a = ["a","b"]

a.count  //2

Comment: But this isn't an `NSArray` and you don't show how to print the count with `NSLog`.