# what does the NSLog array count code shown do?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nslog

```
NSLog(@"%d",[annotations count]);
```

The above code is used with an NSMutableArray named 'annotations'.

My question is... what does this code do exactly?

I know `NSLog` outputs text, and its saying annotations count.. so I am thinking that it outputs the amounts of elements in the annotations array.

Am I correct?

Comment: In Xcode, Option+Click on count and read the content of the pop up.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch what key on a mac would Option be? cmd? alt?

Comment: Don't they label them with "option" anymore? Should be `alt` then.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Yeah, they still say option...  Bottom row from the left on a mac is 'fn', 'control', 'option/alt', 'command'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have just run the code to test this, but yes this command outputs to `NSLog` the count of the array named "annotations". For example if the array contains objects and indexes 0,1,2,3, and 4 the array's count will be 5.

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
NSLog(@"Number of items in my array is: %d", [array count]);//this will return (5)
```

For more details, see this post: [Size of an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512040/size-of-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct exactly.  `NSLog` prints text to the console window, and the `count` function of an array outputs the number of elements in that array.

NSLog prints text in a special way; wherever there is a `%i`, `%d`, `%f`, `%@`, etc, it replaces that symbol with a passed variable.  So if I typed:

```
NSLog(@"Hi my name is %@. I am %i years old.", @"Sarah", 12);
```

The console would print:

```
Hi, my name is Sarah.  I am 12 years old.
```

So in your example, if annotations has 10 elements, `10` will simply be printed to the console.  This can get confusing if you simply print a bunch of numbers though!  So using NSLog's flexibility, it would be easier to read your log output if you did this:

```
NSLog(@"Elements in annotations array: %d", [annotations count]);
```

Then this would be printed to your console:

```
Elements in annotations array: 10
```

Which might be more helpful when reading back through your logs!

Comment: In your first example, you are expecting a string object but supplying a C-style character array (c-string). Fix that by prefixing the Sarah-string by an AT-symbol.

Comment: @Till Meep, sorry!  Thanks for catching the typo!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will simply display the count of objects in the array