# Length of Allocated Array

Tags: objective-c

I have this objective-c code, but I cant find the size of the allocated array.

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Banana",      @"Plum", nil];
[myArray objectAtIndex: 0];
[myArray length];
```

XCode give-me this error:

"No visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector length"

What can this be?

Comment: The correct method is `-[NSArray count]`.

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me this error: "No Known class method for selector 'count'

Comment: Right, count isn't a class method it's an instance method. So you should do [myArray count] as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is length? If you want to find the number of objects in the array use:

```
[myArray count];
```

If you want to find the size, check this link out:

[Length of an Array in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530050/length-of-an-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: It worked, thank you. Strange a little this logic, about counting the number of objects, instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

@Sedate Alien is right. `[myArray count]` or `myArray.count` are the ways to get the length.

It looks like you might be missing something simple like the framework containing `NSArray` ... not sure how, since most templates include it, but just in case make sure you have `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and added the actual framework to your project

Roughly:
(`Project->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries... -> "+" button->Foundation`)