# What ((size_t*)ptr)[-1] mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, size

I want to know the size allocated to a pointer.

So I found this answer :
[how can i know the allocated memory size of pointer variable in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202069/how-can-i-know-the-allocated-memory-size-of-pointer-variable-in-c)

And it has the below code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * my_malloc(size_t s) 
{
  size_t * ret = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + s);
  *ret = s;
  return &ret[1];
}

void my_free(void * ptr) 
{
  free( (size_t*)ptr - 1);
}

size_t allocated_size(void * ptr) 
{
  return ((size_t*)ptr)[-1];
}

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) 
{
  int * array = my_malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
  printf("%u\n", allocated_size(array));
  my_free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

The line `(((size_t*)ptr)[-1])` works perfectly, but I don't understand why...

Can someone help me understand this magic line? Thanks!

Comment: one problem here is that `size_t` might *not* have its size equal to the maximum alignment requirement of all types

Comment: `return &ret[1];` Ooof, that's utterly horrible code.  Continuing what @AnttiHaapala states, since `size_t` might not fit the maximum alignment restriction, use of the pointer returned from `my_malloc()` could fail since it no longer meets the [C standard's requirement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3) of being "suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement".

Comment: I wish voters would read and understand the question before upvoting answers that – regardless of any facts they may or may not contain – do not actually answer the question…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that your compiler's C `malloc` implementation keeps the allocated size (in bytes) in the 4 bytes right before the address it returns.

By converting the returned address (`ptr`) to a pointer-to-`size_t` (that's `((size_t*)ptr)`), and then taking the aligned address right before it (that's the '[-1]', which is actually just pointer arithmetic - same as writing `*(((size_t*)ptr) - 1)`) - you can access the allocated size (of type `size_t`).

This is to explain what `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]` means and why it seems to work, but this is by no means a recommendation on using it. Getting the size allocated to a pointer was a quantity asked by the application-code and should be managed by it if needed, while not relying on compiler implementations.

Comment: Does this work for all malloc implementations or just GNU libc?

Comment: Isn't size of `size_t` undefined? Since `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]` skips from `ptr` by the mentioned size, it isn't determined that it's always 4 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is incorrect.  `malloc()` in SOME implementations may store the size in such a manner, but it is by no means "common" - there are certainly implementations which do no such thing.   It is formally undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. It is okay to explain to readers that **some** implementation of C might store the size of an allocated block before the block, but it is horrible to lead with an unqualified statement that `malloc` does keep the size there. It is simply not true to state that without qualification. Furthermore, even if an implementation does store the size there, that does not mean it supports accessing it via `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]`, which violates standard C rules.

Comment: This answer does not even address the question. In the question, a user routine `my_malloc` is used, not `malloc`, and the size being examined is one stored by `my_malloc`, not one stored by `malloc`.

Answer (score 6):

If `ptr` is pointing to a block of memory allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, etc., then `(((size_t*)ptr)[-1]` invokes *undefined behavior*. My guess is that it is relying on the behavior of some random vendor's implementation of the standard library that happens to store the size of a memory block in the location just before the location returned by `malloc` etc.

DO NOT USE SUCH HACKS! If a program is allocating memory dynamically, it should be able to keep track of the sizes of memory it allocated without relying on undefined behavior.

The size of the memory block actually allocated by `malloc` etc. may be larger than the size requested, so perhaps you are interested in knowing the actual size of the block that was allocated, including the excess memory at the end of the block. Portable code should not need to know this as accessing locations beyond the requested size is also *undefined behavior*, but perhaps you want to know this size for curiousity's sake or for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, now that I know how it works I realise it's not a very stable and safe solution.

Comment: You might find that it only "works" for some block sizes but not for others, even on the same implementation!

Comment: In the code shown in the question, `ptr` is not pointing to a block of memory allocated by `malloc`. The routine `my_malloc` gets memory from `malloc`, stores the size, and returns a pointer to memory just beyond that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It wasn't there when I answered. Also, that code has possible alignment issues.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with what `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]` means.

When you use the array subscript operator as (for example) `A[B]`, this is exactly equivalent to `*(A + B)`.  So what is really happening here is pointer arithmetic followed by a dereference.  This means that having a negative array index is valid, *provided that* the pointer in question doesn't point to the first element of the array.

As an example:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *p = a + 2;
printf("p[0] = %d\n", p[0]);      // prints 3
printf("p[-1] = %d\n", p[-1]);    // prints 2
printf("p[-2] = %d\n", p[-2]);    // prints 1
```

So applying this to `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]`, this says that `ptr` points to an element of an array of one or more objects of type `size_t` (or to one element past the end of the array), and the subscript -1 gets the object *just before* the one `ptr` points to.

Now what does this mean in the context of the sample program?

The function `my_malloc` is a wrapper around `malloc` that allocates `s` bytes **plus** enough bytes for a `size_t`.  It writes the value of `s` at the start of the malloc'ed buffer as a `size_t`, then returns a pointer to the memory **after** the `size_t` object.

So the memory actually allocated and the returned pointer look something like this (assuming `sizeof(size_t) is 8)`:

```
        -----
0x80    | s |
0x81    | s |
0x82    | s |
0x83    | s |
0x84    | s |
0x85    | s |
0x86    | s |
0x87    | s |
0x88    |   |   <--- ptr
0x89    |   |
0x8A    |   |
...
```

When a pointer returned from `my_malloc` is passed to `allocated_size`, the function can read the requested size of the buffer with `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]`:

```
        -----
0x80    | s |   <--- ptr[-1]
0x81    | s |
0x82    | s |
0x83    | s |
0x84    | s |
0x85    | s |
0x86    | s |
0x87    | s |
0x88    |   |   <--- ptr[0]
0x89    |   |
0x8A    |   |
```

The casted `ptr` points to one element past an array of `size_t` of size 1, so the pointer itself is valid and subsequently getting the object with the array subscript -1 is also valid.  This is **not** undefined behavior as others have suggested since the pointer is being converted to/from a `void *` and points to a valid object of the specified type.

In this implementation, only the size of the requested buffer is stored before the returned pointer, however you could store more metadata there provided you allocate enough extra space for it.

The one thing this doesn't take into account is that the memory returned by `malloc` is suitably aligned for any purpose, and the pointer returned by `my_malloc` may not fit that requirement.  So an object placed at the returned address may have an alignment issue and cause a crash.  To account for this, additional bytes would need to be allocated to fit that requirement, and `allocated_size` and `my_free` would also need to be adjusted to account for that.

Comment: Potentially interesting related trivia: due to the equivalence of `A[B]` and `*(A + B)`, it is also possible to use `1[arr]` instead of `arr[1]`. (But please don't.) However, understanding this illustrates why `ptr[-1]` is not automatically broken any more than `*(ptr - 1)` is.

Comment: re. alignment issue, it could be fixable by using `max_align_t` to adjust the offset and alignment of the returned/passed address, instead of assuming `size_t` to have the maximum alignment requirements like the original `my_alloc` does.

Comment: @Arkku Possibly it would need a `union` containing `size_t` and `max_align_t` members, as I don't think it is guaranteed that `max_align_t` can represent all `size_t` values.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I suggested exactly that (union) in the comments of another answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

First, let’s explain what `(((size_t*)ptr)[-1])` does, assuming that it is valid:

- `(size_t*)ptr` converts `ptr` to the type “pointer to `size_t`”.
- `((size_t *)ptr)[-1]` is, by definition<sup>1</sup>, equivalent to `*((size_t *) ptr - 1)`.<sup>2</sup> That is, it subtracts 1 from `(size_t *) ptr` and “deferences” the resulting pointer.
- Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of array elements and treats a single object as an array of one element.<sup>2</sup> If `(size_t *) ptr` is pointing “just beyond” a `size_t` object, then `*((size_t *) ptr - 1)` points to the `size_t` object.
- Thus, `(((size_t*)ptr)[-1])` is the `size_t` object that is just before `ptr`.

Now, let’s discuss whether this expression is valid. `ptr` is obtained by this code:

```
void * my_malloc(size_t s) 
{
  size_t * ret = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + s);
  *ret = s;
  return &ret[1];
}
```

If `malloc` succeeds, it allocates space for any object of the requested size.<sup>4</sup> So we can certainly store a `size_t` there<sup>5</sup>, except that this code ought to check the return value to guard against allocation failure. Furthermore, we may return `&ret[1]`:

- `&ret[1]` is equivalent to `&*(ret + 1)`, which is equivalent to `ret + 1`. This points one beyond the `size_t` we have stored at `ret`, which is valid pointer arithmetic.
- The pointer is converted to the function return type, `void *`, which is valid.<sup>5</sup>

The code shown in the question does only two things with the value returned from `my_malloc`: retrieve the stored size with `((size_t*)ptr)[-1]` and free the space using `(size_t*)ptr - 1`. These are both valid since the pointer conversion is appropriate and they are operating within the limits of pointer arithmetic.

However, there is a question about what further uses the returned value can be put to. As others have noted, while the pointer returned from `malloc` is suitably aligned for any object, the addition of a `size_t` produces a pointer that is suitably aligned only for an object whose alignment requirement is not stricter than `size_t`. For example, in many C implementations, this would mean the pointer could not be used for a `double`, which often requires eight-byte alignment while `size_t` is merely four bytes.

So we immediately see that `my_malloc` is not a full replacement for `malloc`. Nonetheless, perhaps it could be used only for objects with satisfactory alignment requirements. Let’s consider that.

I think many C implementations would have no trouble with this, but, technically, there is a problem here: `malloc` is specified to return space for one object of the requested size. That object can be an array, so the space can be used for multiple objects of the same type. However, it is not specified that the space can be used for multiple objects of different types. So, if some object other than a `size_t` is stored in the space returned by `my_malloc`, I do not see that the C standard defines the behavior. As I noted, this is a pedantic distinction; I do not expect a C implementation to have a problem with this, although increasingly aggressive optimizations have surprised me over the years.

One way to store multiple different objects in the space returned by `malloc` is to use a structure. Then we could put an `int` or a `float` or `char *` in the space after the `size_t`. However, we cannot do so by pointer arithmetic—using pointer arithmetic to navigate the members of a structure is not fully defined. Addressing structure members is properly done by name, not pointer manipulations. So returning `&ret[1]` from `my_malloc` is not a valid way (defined by the C standard) to provide a pointer to space that may be used for any object (even if the alignment requirement is satisfied).

## Other Notes

This code improperly uses `%u` to format a value of type `size_t`:

```
printf("%u\n", allocated_size(array));
```

The specific integer type of `size_t` is implementation-defined and might not be `unsigned`. The resulting behavior may not be defined by the C standard. The proper format specifier is `%zu`.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> C 2018 6.5.2.1 2.

<sup>2</sup> More precisely, it is `*((((size_t *) ptr)) + (-1))`, but these are equivalent.

<sup>3</sup> C 2018 6.5.6 8 and 9.

<sup>4</sup> C 2018 7.22.3.4.

<sup>5</sup> A very pedantic reader of C 2018 7.22.3.4 could object that `size_t` is not an object of the requested size but is an object of smaller size. I do not believe that is the intended meaning.

<sup>6</sup> C 2018 6.3.2.3 1.

Comment: Perhaps there could be `struct allocation { union { size_t size; max_align_t foo; }; max_align_t data[]; }` and the address of `data` would be returned/passed. (edit: Or actually, perhaps just pass the second element of an array of `union { size_t size; max_align_t foo; }` and use the first element for the size.)

Comment: @Arkku: Then you have an aliasing issue. If you have a pointer to `max_align_t`, the compiler is generally entitled to assume that accesses to objects pointed to by pointers of incompatible types do not interact with accesses to objects pointed to by `max_align_t *`.

Comment: How about the use of just an array of unions containing (at least) `size_t` and `max_align_t`? What if we add an array of `char` to the union?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very bad code which invokes the UB .

If he wanted to save the allocated space size he should use the structure where first field is the size, and the second zero sized array (or vla) for the actual  data

Comment: What is the UB?

Comment: use search bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: I meant, what line of code is UB?