# Can't malloc correctly in Objective-C/C

Tags: objective-c, c, malloc

I have an OpenGL program, but can't alloc correctly.

```
m_VertexData = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(m_TempVertexData));
m_NormalData = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(m_TempNormalData));
NSLog(@"sizeOfTempVertex: %d sizeOfTempNormal: %d", sizeof(m_TempVertexData),sizeof(m_TempNormalData));
NSLog(@"sizeOfVertex: %d sizeOfNormal: %d",sizeof(m_VertexData),sizeof(m_NormalData));
```

NSLog:

> sizeOfTempVertex: 432 sizeOfTempNormal: 432
>
> sizeOfVertex: 4 sizeOfNormal: 4

Comment: Well, what types are all the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m_VertexData and m_normalData are pointers, so their size is sizeof (whatever type it has *), so it allocates the correct amount of memory. You need to allocate sizeof(member of the array) * number of items bytes of memory. By the way, a few things related to malloc:

1. Don't cast the return value of malloc. It makes code unreadable and it's unnecessary as void * is implicitly promoted to whatever pointer type it is assigned to.
2. Don't use `sizeof(type)`, rather `sizeof(variable)`. If you ever change the type of the variable, it's gonna cause hard-to-track-down errors.

Considering these points, use the following code:

```
m_VertexData = malloc(sizeof(*m_VertexData) * numberOfItems);
```

Comment: I do not believe that is guaranteed that `sizeof(type*) == sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: Yes it is. Function pointers having the same size as data pointers is not guaranteed.

Comment: While it will likely be equal there is no guarantee, see the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/399030/418715)

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof` tells you the size of the type (calculated at compile-time).  It tells you nothing about how much memory was allocated dynamically.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Except in the special case of C99's variable-length arrays.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

According to the C standard, Section 6.5.3.4.2:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.

In your case, the operands `m_VertexData` and `m_NormalData` are pointers (which makes sense, because you have just assigned to them the result of calling `malloc`). Therefore, their size is the same as the size of any other pointer on your system - 4 bytes.

In case you are wondering, there is no standard way to determine how much memory you have `malloc`-ed; if you need that size for future reference, you need to store that number in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` may not work how you think it works. `sizeOfVertex` and `sizeOfNormal` are both 32-bit pointers, so 4 is the correct size for both of them. There's no portable way to determine the actual size of the allocated memory; see [determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c).