# C - Size of an array which is created by realloc

Tags: c, sizeof, realloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c)

I have a `struct` in my c code, but this question is also valid for all other types so I will use `int` instead of `struct` I created.

```
int *a = realloc(NULL, 10*sizeof(int) );
printf("%d\n",sizeof(a)); //prints 4, needed to be 40

int b[10];
printf("%d\n",sizeof(b)); //prints 40
```

My question is this: I am using `realloc` in my code and I don't know how I can find the total size of my array. What is the easiest way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you want on pointers. You can simply not "forget" what you passed to `realloc`.

Comment: @PaulR Compile time ? What about `VLAs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time (except with VLA, but it's not your case). Imagine that you take the size of `realloc` argument as user's input : it's impossible to the compiler to know the real allocated size. So it returns the size of the pointer.

Comment: "evaluated at compile-time" - not true for C99 apparently, where sizeof works with VLAs at run-time (I learned something new today !).

Comment: I understood. So is there any function that can calculate its size dynamically or should I keep its size in a variable?

Comment: You need to track allocation sizes yourself - there is no portable way of getting this information after the fact.

Comment: @Paul R : Yes, C99's VLA are an exception : but it's a very strange subject and sometimes a bad thing (there are optionnal with C11, so I don't use them at all... Almost deprecied...).

Comment: @ibrahim : There is no portable way to get this size. Store your size into a data structure, it's the better way !

Answer (score 0):

In short it's something that you'll need to store in your code, and pass around to your various functions.  Since you passed that information into `realloc` it's available already.

Also remember that sizeof won't work on pointers, it only will return the size of the pointer, not the size of the memory that the pointer points at.

Answer (score 0):

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

```
In the programming languages C and C++, the unary operator sizeof
is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the
number of bytes required to represent the type.
```

This means that this

```
sizeof( int* )
```

returns size of pointer on your architecture. And if you want to know the size of your array, you have to do:

```
sizeof( your_type ) * array_size
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)` returns the size of the *pointer* not what it points to. You have to keep track of that yourself if you allocate memory with `malloc` or `realloc`.