# Array of arrays, with different sizes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having an array, that has arrays in every cell. For example, the big array is called `arr`:

```
int a[3] = {3, 2, 1};
int b[2] = {2, 1};
int *arr[2] = {a, b}
```

Now the problem is, if I want to print the small arrs, inside the big array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArr(int arr [], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 8, 4, 2, 0};
    int b[3] = {1, 4, 2};
    int *arr [2] = {a, b};

    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        printArr(*(arr + i), n);
    }
}
```

The output is supposed to be something like this:

`1 8 4 2 0
1 4 2`

But I can't get the size of each array, since `sizeof(*(arr + i)` gives me 4, which is the size of the pointer (the name of the array), and not all the array it self.
So what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a structure that can store the size of the array as well and make an array of such structs?
BTW, try `sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[i][0])`?

Comment: Is there a way without using a struct ?
and `sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[i][0])` returns 1, when theres 5 elements...

Comment: sizeof(arr[i]) gives you the size of an int pointer and sizeof(arr[i][0] gives you the size of an int. You can not get the size of the array itself with that method

Comment: Well, then there's no way. `sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[i][0])` works if arr[i] is an array and not a pointer.
C doesn't store array sizes. So your best bet is to use a struct like `struct {int *arr; int size;}` and make an array of such structs.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c

Comment: If you cannot avoid arrays, can you try this? `int a[6] = {<size of array>, 2,3,4,5}`

Comment: Thanks @cppcoder, I guess I'll really "cheat" and put the size at the start!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***The Problem:***

The C language only provides a way of finding the size of types.
This gives the subtle differences between applying `sizeof` to:

1) An array of a type such as:

```
int a[3];
sizeof(a); // => 3 * sizeof(int)
```

2) A pointer to the type:

```
int *ptr;
sizeof(ptr); // => sizeof(int *)
```

or

```
int a[3] = {3, 2, 1};
int b[2] = {2, 1};
int *arr[2] = {a, b};

sizeof(arr[1]); // => sizeof(int *)
```

***Some solutions:***

**Store the size**

As jfly proposes store the size of the arrays.

- Makes finding the size a constant time operation.

**Append an end marker**

Adding a end marker like `'\0'` as used for c-style strings.
You might use `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` in this case.

The `printArr` implementation would need to change to:

```
void printArr(int *arr)
{
    int *it = arr;
    while(arr != INT_MIN);
    {
        printf("%d ", *it);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

*Disadvantages:*

- Finding the size of the array requires iterating over the full array.
- Gives the risk of an actual value colliding with the end marker value.

*Advantages:*

- The varying sized array can be passed as a single argument.

**Using iterators**

Store the pointer to the first and one past the last value.

```
void printArr(int *begin, int *end)
{
    for (int *it = begin; it != end; it++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *it);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int *end_arr[2] = {a + 3, b + 2};

for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
{
    printArr(arr[i], end_arr[i]);
}
```

- Can be extended to other data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Since `arr` is an array of pointers, so you can't get the size of array from the pointer which  points to an array, you need additional size info:

```
    int size_arr[2] = {sizeof(a) / sizeof(int), sizeof(b) / sizeof(int)};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        printArr(arr[i], size_arr[i]);
    }
```