# How to make an array of arrays with different sizes in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I am going to have an array of arrays in c as each array in the main array has a specific size. For example:
    {
     {a,b,c},
     {a},
     {a,d}
    }
 The problem is I don't want to use heap memory and to use "malloc", also it should not be any wasted memory. For example I don't want to use following code:

```
char myArrays[][3] = {
 {a,b,c},
 {a,null,null},
 {a,d,null}
}
```

Comment: Check this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745750/array-of-arrays-with-different-sizes ??

Comment: 3 bytes isn't really wasting memory… Do you suffer from little memory in your actual project or is this a rather theoretical question?

Comment: Precise the questions, what is supposed to be a b c d null etc and add the context of your problem.

Comment: `null` is not a valid `char`. Neither are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Did you mean `'a'` and `'\0'` instead?

Comment: I am not certain, but I think you are asking for Rearden Metal or Unobtainium.

Comment: @BenKey Ah well, there is always a way. :-)

Comment: Do the arrays have always the same lenght? E.g. the second element is always length 1 (e.g. {a})?

Comment: This is a POS programming and the memory that I care for is so much than some bytes. @mafso

Comment: Yes, you are right @dasblinkenlight , but it does not changes the problem ;)

Comment: No, as I said they may have different sizes. @PeterSchneider

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make an array of arrays of different sizes, you need to make an array of pointers, like this:

```
char *myArrays[] = {
    (char[]){'a','b','c'},
    (char[]){'a'},
    (char[]){'a','d'}
};
```

You do not need to "pad" your arrays with null characters.

Note that this approach does not provide an easy way of finding out the exact length of inner arrays: `sizeof` operator is not going to work. If you want to know the lengths of the inner arrays, either add terminating entries of some sort (say, `'\0'`s) or add an array of lengths, like this:

```
size_t myLengths[] = {3, 1, 2};
```

Now you can iterate the array of arrays like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != myLengths[i] ; j++) {
        putchar(myArrays[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/WOQLEy)

Comment: Does that really work? Neat.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Absolutely, it does! I added a demo.

Comment: To clarify for those who've been living under a rock the past 15 years: this solution uses the C concept of _compound literals_ which was introduced with the C99 standard. (It's not really necessary to use them though, you might as well declare each array as an individual variable and achieve the very same result.)

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight , but let suppose that I have defined a _struct_ in my code. Does your answer works to make a array of arrays of pointers to my instances of the _struct_ ?

Comment: @rezCash Yes, you could use this concept with expressions defined in code ([demo](http://ideone.com/0DaEBb)). Of course you need to pay attention to the scope of that array and the `struct`s that go into it in order to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array of pointers:

```
char* ptrArray [] =
{
  array1,
  array2,
  ...
};
```

To keep track of their individual sizes, either declare another array with the same size containing the sizes, or embedded the arrays in structs, where the size is one member and the pointer to the array another.

Comment: It may you mean that I should declare each array and then use them in _ptrArray_ , but I want just initiate each array in the main array.

Comment: @rezCash For what purpose? Do you have any rational reason for wanting to have them in the same array, or do you just "feel" that way?

Answer (score -1):

Now in C++ you could make a vector of vectors. Something like the following.

```
std::vector< std::vector<char> > myArrays;
myArrays.resize(3);
myArrays[0].resize(3);
myArrays[1].resize(1);
myArrays[2].resize(2);
```

But this is C++ and not C. In addition, std::vector uses heap memory behind the scenes.

But this is the closest to what you have asked for that I can think of.

Comment: The question is about C, so your answer is off-topic and irrelevant. Also the OP specifically asked for a solution that doesn't use heap memory.