# Fill an array with arrays in different sizes

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, fill

I am looking for an efficient and nice way to fill an array with arrays in different sizes. I am thinking of a solution like:

```
private bool arrayMaking(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value, out int[] arrays)
{
    arrays = {array1, array2, value};
    return true;
}
```

Is there a possible solution or do I need to loop?

Comment: What is the expected result? A input / output example would help

Comment: oh sorry, my original method is much more complex and I tried to break it down to the essential part. The return `bool` is not relevant for the array filling process, the method can be void, too.
In my Method I check, if the values in `array1` and `array2` are okay. If yes, I return the solution shown, if not, I try to change the values of array2 and after the adaption I fill the `arrays` with `{array1, array2, value}`. If the adaption is not possible, I return false.
The code posted throws an error in Visual Studio, saying "Invalid Expression "{""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of arrays, with different sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745750/array-of-arrays-with-different-sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you want to merge one or more arrays into single Array. You could do this using `Concat` (or `Union` to eliminate duplicates).

```
private bool arrayMaking(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value, out int[] arrays)
{
    arrays = array1.Concat(array2).Concat( new int[] {value}).ToArray();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was searching for! Works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the array from the two other arrays and the `int`, you could use:

```
private bool ArrayMaking(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value, out int[] arrays)
{
    int size = array1.Length + array2.Length + 1;
    arrays = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        arrays[i] = array1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
        arrays[i + array1.Length] = array2[i];
    arrays[arrays.Length - 1] = value;
    return true;
}
```

less efficient but more readable using LINQ:

```
private bool ArrayMaking(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value, out int[] arrays)
{
    arrays = array1.Concat(array2).Concat(new[] {value}).ToArray();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Jagged Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) ?

You can also [create an Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549399/c-sharp-creating-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to solve your problem:

```
// Make sure to add these first:
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

private bool arrayMaking(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value, out int[] arrays)
{
    List<int> array = new List<int>();
    array.AddRange(array1);
    array.AddRange(array2);
    array.Add(value);
    arrays = array.ToArray();
    return true;
}
```