# How to find Dynamically allocated size in c language?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc, allocation

Write a function to find exact size of dynamically created * variable ?

```
Guys it is working but for static allocation only...

int alp=0;
printf("%d",(char*)(&alp+1)-(char*)(&alp));
```

**it will return 4 correct size, which is size of int at 32 bit machine** but not working with dynamically allocated pointer variable.

```
char *c=(char *)malloc(12*sizeof(char));
```

How to find size of ***c** which is actually **12** here ??

please Help me to write a function to find dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: You can't, you'll need to keep track of it yourself (in a separate variable).

Comment: By the way, [In C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858), or any other function returning `void *`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c)

Comment: The size is the size you allocated. But because you used a hard-coded `12` you have made life difficult for yourself. Your question is not comparing like with like. If you did the same exercise using the `char*` pointer as you did with `int*` you would get corresponding result.

Answer (score 3):

The short and only answer is that you can't. You simply have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: helo sir, I have read somewhere last block point to the first block.
When request is made free list is scanned until big enough block is found. And if the block is too big , it is split , and proper amount is returned to user. Is and way to found it.

Comment: @srhaider *Some* memory allocators may work that way, but there is no standardized memory allocator system, and the only way to take a peek at the internal data used by the memory allocator is to go out of bounds of the memory returned to your application, and that's technically *undefined behavior*. The ***only*** standard way to get the size of a dynamic memory allocation is to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: There's a gnu extension to do just that: `malloc_usable_size()`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know programmatically how many bytes were allocated in a call to `malloc()`.  You need to keep track of that size separately and pass that size around where needed.

For example:

```
void myfunc(char *c, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        printf("c[%d]=%c\n",size,c[size]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int len=10;
    char *c = malloc(len);
    strcpy(c,"hello");
    myfunc(c,len);
    free(c);
}
```

Comment: Do you pass type of data ant size of it in sizeof operator too.

Comment: @srhaider The `sizeof` operator takes a single operand which is either a type name in parenthesis or a variable or literal.  It doesn't take the size, since that's what it's returning to you.

Comment: @srhaider `sizeof(c)` in this instance will evaluate to the size of a `char *`, since that is the type of `c`.  It will most likely evaluate to either 4 or 8, depending on how big a pointer is on your system.