# Not getting the actual size of allocated memory to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, sizeof

I am trying to allocate space for 100 integers. But end up with 2 and have not a clue why! I tried both `malloc()` and `calloc` but understandingly there is no difference.

Code:

```
#define MAX 100

    int *arr = (int *)calloc(MAX, sizeof(int)); //same with malloc(MAX * sizeof(int))

    printf("MAIN before memset: %d | %d\n",
    (int)(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])), (int)(sizeof(arr)));

    if(!arr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A malloc error occured.\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    memset (arr, 0, MAX);
    printf("MAIN: %d\n", (int)(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])));
```

OUTPUT:

```
MAIN before memset: 2 | 8
MAIN: 2
```

What am I coming short of? I simply want to allocate an array/pointer to 100 integers.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: it is the same without the cast

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/492384/694576

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `arr` is a pointer, and using `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of the pointer, not the amount of memory allocated to that pointer.

In your case, `sizeof(arr)` gives you the size of a `int *` and `sizeof(arr[0])` gives you the size of an `int`, based on your platform and compiler.

That said, you cannot directly get the size of allocated memory *from* the pointer itself, you need to keep track of it yourself.