# Prime generator using a huge array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I'm trying to make a prime number generator using arrays. I started with a 1D array but the max limit on my computer was 250000. So I thought maybe I should make a 2d or more array to go to the next line once this limit is reached to avoid problems on my PC. But I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be welcome.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<time.h>
#define LIMIT 250000ul

//prime number generator using arrays 

void prime_generator(){

    unsigned long long n; 
    printf("How many primes do you want generated : "); 
    scanf("%llu", &n);

    unsigned long long p[LIMIT];  
    unsigned long long i, j=2; 
    unsigned long long num; 
    bool isPrime; 

    unsigned long long primes_per_line, space_column; 
    printf("How many primes do you want displayed per line? : "); 
    scanf("%llu", &primes_per_line); 
    printf("Enter space : "); 
    scanf("%llu", &space_column); 

    p[0]=2, p[1]=3;//first two primes
    unsigned long long count = 2; 

    clock_t begin = clock();   
    for(num = 5;count < n; num=num+2){//only test for odd number 
        isPrime = true; 
        for(i = 1;i < j && p[i] <= sqrt(num) ;i++){
            if(num%p[i]==0){
                isPrime = false;  
                break;//break out of i loop 
            }
        }
        if(isPrime == true){
            ++count; 
            p[j] = num; //new prime found 
            ++j; 
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock(); 
    double time_spent = (double) (end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i!=0 && i % primes_per_line == 0) printf("\n"); 
        printf("%*llu", space_column, p[i]); 
    }

    printf("\nCrunching time is : %.12f", time_spent);
}

int main(void){
    prime_generator(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Changing the dimension of the array doesn't increase the amount of memory you have available to you.

Comment: A 2D array is not going to take less memory than a 1D array. Look into using dynamic memory instead - ie, call `malloc`. Better still, improve your algorithm to not need so much memory.

Comment: Look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Comment: If your compiler does not "see inside" `sqrt(num)`, then that function will be repetitively called - unnecessarily.  Suggest `unsigned long long limit = llrint(sqrt(num)); for(i = 1;i < j && p[i] <= limit;i++){ ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `unsigned long long p[LIMIT];` is a *local* variable (with [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)) inside your `prime_generator` function, so it is on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (which is often limited to one or a few megabytes).  Declare it as a [`static`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)) or make it a *global* variable (in both cases, it gets a [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)). Then it could be much larger, but your `prime_generator` won't be [re-entrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) anymore (but in your case, you don't care).

Declaring an array as multi-dimensional won't improve its memory size (so won't solve the problem of an excessive call frame size of a variable declared *local*).

Better yet, use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) that is [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) (don't forget to test it against failure, when it returns `NULL` use `perror` then `exit`) and [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free); beware of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak); tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could be helpful. With `calloc` (or `malloc`) you'll then grow your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and be limited by machine and system resources (probably gigabytes).

Avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194976/841108).

Read also wikipages on [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and on [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). There are more efficient algorithms.

You should be able to compute a million primes (ending with 15485761
15485773
15485783
15485801
15485807
15485837
15485843
15485849
15485857
15485863)
in a few seconds at most (and probably in less than half a second).