# Do I risk a buffer overrun here and how would I avoid it?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, string-literals

I implemented an easy list structure where single list elements are defined by the following structure:

```
struct list_elem {
    struct list_elem *next;  // ptr to the next element
    char             *data;  // ptr to data
};
```

Now, I want to do the following:

```
struct list_elem *elem;
int main() {
    elem->data = "some_string";
    strcat(elem->data, "another_string");
}
```

I am worried about an overrun because the man page of strcat states:

> The `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. **If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable**; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

And basically I got no idea how much memory is allocated for my list element.

Comment: there are ways to know how many bytes were allocated, only if `data` is the result of `malloc`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281720/6451573

Comment: For your list element: No memory is allocated. `elem` is `NULL`. For your string: 12 bytes are allocated (`'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', '_', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'`).

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
elem->data = "some_string";
```

makes the `data` pointer point to string literal `"some_string"`.
And here:

```
strcat(elem->data, "another_string");
```

you are trying to copy string literal `"another_string"` to a pointer which is pointing to another string literal. As per the standard attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior because it may be stored in read-only storage.

You should allocate memory to `data`, like this:

```
elem->data = calloc(50, 1); // sizeof (char) is 1
```

Then copy the `"some_string"` to it;

```
strcpy (elem->data, "some_string");
```

Then concatenate `"another_string"` to it:

```
strcat (elem->data, "another_string");
```

Alternatively, you can use `snprintf()` also:

```
snprintf (elem->data, 49, "%s%s", "some_string", "another_string");
```

EDIT:

Thanks @alk for pointing this.

The `elem` pointer is not pointing to valid memory. 
You should first allocate memory to the `struct list_elem` pointer `elem`, like this:

```
elem = malloc (sizeof (struct list_elem));
if (elem == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: Please note that per the OP's code `elem` is not pointing to valid memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for astrxxx functions(,which are not standard C functions). They dynamically allocates memories while operation.
[Github example implementations](http://%20https://github.com/haneefmubarak/snippets/blob/develop/astrcat.c)

- `astrcat` is implemented above.
- `asprintf` is a dynamic version of sprintf.
- and more are provided by some GNU compilers

**Note: you SHOULD FREE dynamically allocated memories!!**

Plus, you should use it like this:

```
struct list_elem elem;    //removed *, as it can cause seg fault if not initialized. you have to initialize by using struct list_elem * elem=malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem)); or something.
int main() {
    elem.data = strdup("some_string");//you must free data later
    astrcat(&elem.data, "another_string");
    //use it
    free(elem.data);
}
```

First, the `struct list_elem* elem` is initialized as `NULL`, so it has to be initialized with valid address before `->` statements.
You can assign a pointer to the data section to the `data`, which cannot be modified normally.

Comment: he doesn't need to use array of chars in the struct. the space could be allocated on concatenation itself

Comment: @mangusta: "*the space could be allocated on concatenation itself*" what exactly do you want to express, please?

Comment: Please note that `astrcat()` and `aprintf()` are not Standard C, nor `strdup()` is.

Comment: "*the `struct list_elem* elem` is not initialized*" it is, as being a global, it is initialised to `NULL`, which in fact does not help a lot.