# showing wrong value of allocated memory size using malloc in codeblocks

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc

size of allocated memory

```
int main() {

    char *aPtr[10];

    aPtr[0] = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    aPtr[0] = "This is a test";

    aPtr[1] = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    aPtr[1] = "This is a test2";

    printf("%s\n%s\n", aPtr[0], aPtr[1]);

    printf("%d", sizeof(aPtr[0]));
}
```

In this case why the size of the `aPtr[0]` is showing 4 bytes instead of showing 20 bytes. I don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 4):

`aPtr` is an *array of pointers to char*.  So each element of `aPtr` is a single pointer to `char`, or `char *`.  In particular, `aPtr[0]` is a `char *`.  So `sizeof(aPtr[0])` gives you the size of that pointer.  On many machines (on "32 bit machines"), the size of a pointer is 32 bits, or 4 bytes.

Based on your question, it sounds like you're interested in the size of the data the pointer points to.  That's completely different.  (Again, realize carefully the distinction we're making between *the pointer* and *the pointed-to data*.)  And in this case, finding the size of the pointed-to data can be tricky, and it turns out it probably won't involve the `sizeof` operator at all.

If you want to find out the size of a malloc'ed block of memory, it turns out there's no portable way to do that.  That is, after you say `p = malloc(20)`, there's no way to ask "Hey, `malloc`.  That pointer you gave me, that I asked you to allocate some memory for, how much memory did I ask you to allocate, again?  I forget."  If you need to know how much memory your malloc'ed pointers point to, *you* have to remember it somehow.

If you want to find out how long a string is, on the other hand, that's simple: just call `strlen`.  For example, a reasonable fix to your program is to have the last line be

```
printf("%d", strlen(aPtr[0]));
```

Actually, since `strlen` (like `sizeof`) returns a special type called `size_t` that might be bigger than an `int`, the more portable way to write this would be

```
printf("%zu", strlen(aPtr[0]));
```

or

```
printf("%d", (int)strlen(aPtr[0]));
```

But going back to your original program, there's another misunderstanding we should talk about.  You said

```
aPtr[0] = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
aPtr[0] = "This is a test";
```

Now, I know you've been taught that memory allocation is important, and that's true, but in this case, it turns out you're allocating 20 bytes of memory and then throwing it away.  Look closely: `malloc` returns a pointer value (pointing to the newly-allocated memory), and you assign it to (you store the value in) `aPtr[0]`.  But then, in the very next line, you assign `aPtr[0]` to a *different* pointer, pointing to the statically-allocated string `"This is a test"`.  The previous value, the one returned by `malloc`, is lost.

What you probably meant to write here was

```
aPtr[0] = malloc(20);
strcpy(aPtr[0], "This is a test");
```

Now we're doing something completely different with that string constant `"This is a test"`.  Instead of simply assigning a pointer to it, we're copying the while string (actually the library function `strcpy` is copying the whole string) byte-by-byte into the pointer pointed to by `aPtr[0]`, that is, the pointer you just got back from `malloc`.  (In this latest example I have also dropped the unnecessary cast of `malloc`'s return value to `(char *)`, and the unnecessary multiplication by `sizeof(char *)`.)

Notice that in this case (now that you're actually using the malloc'ed memory), the size of the malloc'ed memory matters.  If you had said

```
aPtr[0] = malloc(10);
strcpy(aPtr[0], "This is a test");
```

then you'd have a big problem.

Finally, there's one other answer to the question, "How big is the string?", although it's not usually too useful, and it's certainly not useful in this case.  But if you want to you can write

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("This is a test"));
```

and this will print 15.  (It prints one more than what you thought the string length was, because the count of the size of the string constant includes the terminating `\0` character.)

Comment: If you don't need the extra space at the end, `aPtr[0] = malloc(20); strcpy(aPtr[0], "This is a test");` can be replaced with `aPtr[0] = strdup("This is a test");`.

Answer (score 1):

You are having an array of `char` pointers. So the size of a pointer and size of what it's pointing to is different. Here you are printing the size of a pointer which is fixed i.e, for a 32-bit machine it's 4 bytes.

Comment: "*the size of a pointer which is generally fixed*" just drop "generally". The `sizeof` a pointer variable/type "always" is fixed.

Comment: @alk, Pointers are not always the same size on same machine. So I feel *"generally"* is right word here. You can refer [this article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Pointer_sizes)

Comment: I did not say pointers were "*always the same size*", I just tried to point out that a pointer's size "is fixed", will say: does not change.

Answer (score 1):

> *why the size of the aPtr[0] is showing 4 bytes instead of` showing 20 bytes.*

From [the docs](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand.**

In your case `aPtr[0]` is a pointer to `char`. Pointer types in your environment seem to be 4 bytes wide

In C there is no portable way to from a pointer derive the size of valid memory it is pointing to. See also this answer: [Determine size of dynamically allocated memory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281686/694576)