# Why the C standard doesn't expose a function to get the size of a malloc'ed block?

Tags: c

Say that you allocate some memory on the heap through `malloc`:

```
someType x  = malloc(someSize);
```

When you don't need `x` anymore, you `free` it:

```
free(x)
```

To perform this operation, I guess, the compiler must know the size of the memory `x` points to. I think `free` performs something like:

1. Read the value contained in `x` (say it is 16).
2. Determine *in some way* the memory size allocated at 16 (say it's 8).
3. Tell OS that the 16-23 memory region is not longer needed and the OS can do whatever it wants with it.

If the above is true, why the standard doesn't prescribe a function that just performs the above till step 2 and returns the size to the programmer, without actually freeing the memory?

Some (not much convincing) reasons I read online:

- *`malloc()` implementations usually keep track of a region's size, but they may do this indirectly, or round it up to some value, or not keep it at all*. It's that true? Can possibly `malloc` not keep track of the size?
- *Because C is a low-level programming language, it expects you to take care of these issues yourself, but this adds greater flexibility in exactly how you implement it*. Ok, this is more philosophical. Nonetheless, C standard has evolved and has provided, over time, more headers, functions and tools.
- *You should rewrite every compiler to implement such function*. Is that true? If `free` is already implemented, you just need a part of it; the implementation should be trivial.

**So, there is a cogent, impellent, real reason why this function is not provided? Or, more likely, why the above reasons are actually important and what I am missing?**

I think that this question has been already asked (and very likely a dupe), but I was able only to find similar subjects, for instance (btw the below questions are where I found some of the objections I reported above):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c) is discussed whether such function exists, but not why it doesn't.

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237286/why-do-c-arrays-not-keep-track-of-their-length) is discussed about (stack-allocated)arrays.

Comment: The `malloc` and `free` calls aren't handled by the compiler itself, but the "standard library". How the library implements it differs, and sometime it could be using the native allocator of the operating system in which case it doesn't know anything about sizes either.

Comment: It's not the compiler which knows the size of the block, but the OS and the programmer who allocated it.

Comment: @WeatherVane When you call `free` you don't say: `free this size`; you just provide the pointer. So the compiler must know how much memory is allocated. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't say "free this size", it says "free the block starting at this address". It's the allocator who takes care of how much to free, and the allocator may reside in the OS, with the compiler not knowing about it.

Comment: @nicola The compiler doesn't know anything. It's the `c` standard library which implements the `malloc` and `free` functions and that's completely independent by the compiler itself.

Comment: No, the compiler knows nothing about it. The size might not even be known during compilation. If it was, an array could be used.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see what you say, but so the problem is another. When you `malloc`, somewhere the size is stored. So you just expose a function that returns the size, that's my question.

Comment: @nicola one reason it is absent, is because it isn't necessary. After `malloc(x)` you already know `x` since it was your own code that set it.

Comment: @moooeeeep Thank you, I was sure that it was a dupe. Couldnt' find it. This question can be closed as dupe IMO.

Comment: @WeatherVane One might argue that most of the functions of, say, `string.h` aren't necessary, but they are there.

Comment: @nicola that's rather different, for example `strlen` is used because the programmer doesn't yet know the length of a string entered by the user at run time.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure, but it would be trivial to implement. So it's not necessary.

Comment: You can implement your own `malloc` too if you want.

Comment: Indeed. That's my point. The "necessity" point is not a reason why a function is provided or not.

Comment: The allocation size stored in the control block (if there is indeed such a thing) is *not necessarily* the size passed to `malloc`. Exposing it won't do you much good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is completely unnecessary. The user who called `malloc()` already knows the size s/he asked for. If they want to store it, they can use a variable to do that. They could even store it inside the malloc'd memory itself!

Secondly, when you call `malloc(size)`, you almost never get a memory block of exactly `size` bytes. The only thing the standard guarantees is that you get at least `size` bytes. This difference could be due to reasons like alignment, using larger block sizes to prevent fragmentation, etc..

Now, let's suppose that the standard library were to provide a function of the kind that you asked. Should it give you the allocated size or the requested size? The allocated size is heavily implementation dependent and practically meaningless since you are only allowed to access as many bytes as you initially asked for. If you go beyond that, it is undefined behaviour. If you say requested size, the implementation only needs the allocated size to handle the free, so why should it waste memory storing the requested size as well?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199351/discussion-on-answer-by-th33lf-why-the-c-standard-doesnt-expose-a-function-to-g).

Answer (score 5):

Such a function does not exist since nobody has managed to convince the C standards committee of its necessity.

Providing it might also require additional interfacing with the operating system - where such memory tasks are often delegated, so that could require changes to be made in order to implement the new functionality. That could damage the reputation of C as being supported by many platforms.

Lastly, what would you use it for? I can't conject a use case. If you want to keep track of allocated sizes yourself, then create stub functions for `malloc`, `realloc`, &c.

Comment: I like a lot the first sentence and the fact that it requires some work. Of course it's not necessary, but it might be handy. Many functions provided by the standard aren't actually necessary.