# Why C standard library does not provide a function for knowing the size of allocated memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, size

When some amount of memory is dynamically allocated via calling `malloc()`, the OS internally stores the amount of allocated memory somehow (to track the used memory etc.), so we only provide the pointer to `free()` when we don't need that memory chunk anymore.

However, we [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c) retrieve that size having only the pointer in a portable and OS/compiler-independent way. There exist some non-portable ways like [_msize](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=vs-2019) on Windows/Visual C, or [malloc_usable_size](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html) in glibc. So, the only way is still to propagate all needed sizes along with respective pointers etc., which can be very error-prone.

So, the question is: Why C standard developers decided not to include a portable function into the standard?

P.S. It may be improper to ask "Why" since it usually does involve opinion-based things at least in some extent, but here I believe there's some fundamental reason to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no technical issue stopping the C Standard committee from adding a new library function to retrieve the number of bytes accessible via a valid pointer previously returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `aligned_alloc()`, `strdup()` or any similar function. The number returned would not necessarily be the size initially passed to the allocation function, and it is conceivable that this information might be not be available at all, so a return value of `0` would indicate that the information is not available.

The reason such a function has not yet been added might be that the C Standard committee is usually very reluctant at adding new functions. For example it took more than 30 years for `strdup()` to finally make its way into the C Standard (it will be part of the next version) despite consistent implementations having been available in most C libraries for decades.

This function would have undefined behavior for any pointer not previously returned by a memory allocation function or already freed, just like `free` or `realloc`. Whether it is defined for `NULL` is debatable, but a return value of `0` seems appropriate in this case. If the size is not known, which is possible for dummy allocators that do not store this information, a return value of `0` would indicate this condition too.

Here is an abstract from the man page for `malloc_usable_size` present in the GNU lib C:

> **NAME**
>
> `malloc_usable_size` - obtain size of block of memory allocated from heap
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <malloc.h>
>     
>    size_t malloc_usable_size(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `malloc_usable_size()`  function  returns  the  number  of  usable bytes in the block pointed to by `ptr`, a pointer to a block of memory allocated by `malloc(3)` or a related function.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `malloc_usable_size()` returns the number of usable bytes in the block of allocated memory pointed to  by  `ptr`. If `ptr` is `NULL`, `0` is returned.
>
> **ATTRIBUTES**
>
> Multithreading (see `pthreads(7)`): the `malloc_usable_size()` function is thread-safe.
>
> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> This function is a GNU extension.
>
> **NOTES**
>
> The  value  returned by `malloc_usable_size()` may be greater than the requested size of the allocation because of alignment and minimum size constraints.  Although the excess bytes can be overwritten by  the  application  without  ill  effects,  this  is  not  good programming practice: the number of excess bytes in an allocation  depends on the underlying implementation.
>
> The main use of this function is for debugging and introspection.
>
> **SEE ALSO**
>
> `malloc(3)`

Comment: .. the value returned could also be non-zero and incorrect.  If another thread frees or reallocs the block as the 'allocsize' function returns....

Comment: @MartinJames: of course, any unprotected concurrent access to shared variables invokes undefined behavior. Merely dereferencing a pointer that another thread can free concurrently has undefined behavior too.

Comment: Is the behavior for "offset" pointers well-defined for `malloc_usable_size`? I.e. `char *x = malloc(N); x += 8`. In my simple tests it returned `0` (unknown?). Is this a guaranteed behavior? I want to use it to check if the pointer point to the start of the allocation (as in returned by malloc) or not.

Comment: @DanM.:  Not at all: `malloc_usable_size` has undefined behavior for any non null pointer not returned by an allocation function or already freed. If you add an offset to implement *tagged pointers*, you must remove this *offset* from tagged pointers you pass to this function, as well as `free()` or `realloc()`. Assuming allocated pointer are 16 byte aligned and you use 4 bit tags, you should write `malloc_usable_size((void *)((uintptr_t)(x) & ~15))` to get the actual object pointer. Beyond an offset of 15, there is no reliable way to compute the original pointer returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: @DanM.: If you map memory yourself using `mmap`, you can detect if the pointer `x` points the the beginning of a page by testing its low 12 of so bits, depending on the system page size, but again, this is not a generic solution for offsets beyond 4095.

Comment: @DanM.:  For a generic solution, you can store allocated pointer values in a hash table or some other fast access structure and look up `x` to check if it does point to the beginning of the block... performance should be fine with a hash table, but be careful to add all pointer values when you allocate new blocks and to remove them when you free them.

Comment: @chqrlie yeah, has table probably won't cut it perf-wise. I want to be able to "instrument" all allocations in the lib (i.e. add a 4-8 bytes of info before the allocation), but the problem is the allocations coming from the "outside". I want to be able to detect when I need to adjust the pointer before freeing it and when I don't (for example if it's coming from `strdup`).

Comment: @DanM.: I guess you should instrument `strdup()` too.  For your use case, if the offset is less than 16, testing the low 4 bits of the pointer is a simple solution because pointers returned by `malloc()` are 16-byte aligned on current desktop systems. Be aware that misaligning pointers returned by your wrappers is a problem: this will cause misaligned accesses to members of allocated structures. Make sure you to keep them at least 8-byte aligned. Alternately, you could keep the ancillary information in a separate place, for example in the hash table. Don't underestimate hash table efficiency:)

Answer (score 6):

Because you can get pointers to things that aren't returned from `malloc` and friends.

```
int x = 10;
int * p = &x;
```

The function you're talking about would have to figure out whether or not `p` is returned from `malloc` (possibly expensive).  If it's not (as in this case), it has no way of knowing the amount of space allocated.  You'd also run into problems if you got a pointer to something allocated by `malloc`, but not the exact pointer allocated by `malloc`.

```
int * p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int * p2 = p + 5;
```

What's the right result if I ask for the size of `p2`?

A more consistent approach involves passing sizes along where they're needed.  This lets you work with addresses regardless of where they came from, including offsets to some block of memory (e.g., arrays, like I'm doing with `p2` above).

Comment: I don't agree with the first paragrah, If that was the reason, I don't think `free` existed, C doesn't have a protective API (is protective a correct word?)

Comment: @DavidRanieri, it is true that a function such as the OP asks about could carry the same restriction as `free`, that the argument must be a pointer returned by an allocation function and not subsequently freed.  But so what?  In order to accommodate use of pointers such as those Stephen mentions, most code needs to be written with the assumption that the hypothetical size function cannot be used, therefore it would serve little purpose to provide such a function.  Freeing is a different use case altogether.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes it would be very error prone, but is there anything that is not error prone when it comes to pointers? Without going any further: dereferencing `void *` with an incorrect type, it is something that the compiler cannot control, not even emit a warning, but `void *` is useful.

Comment: @DavidRanieri, the problem is not that a magic memory size function would be error prone.  It is that it would be *unsuited* for most cases, and *unnecessary* for almost all the rest.  Again, such a function could have been provided, with the same limitations as `free`, but it would go largely unused, as indeed the implementation-specific examples presented in the question do.  Remember that this is not in any case a question of feasibility, but of second-guessing the decision process of those charged with writing and maintaining the standard.