# Not being printed out when using fgets

Tags: c, memset, file-pointer

I'm learning about file input/output in C. But there is something I don't understand.
I was about to *print the simple sentence* in the **[words.txt]** using fgets, but it doesn't work.

**[words.txt]** as below:

```
This speech caused a remarkable sensation among the party.
```

And my code is :

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer = malloc(100);
    memset(buffer, 0, 100);

    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");

    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    fclose(fp);

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is "This sp"

I thought there was no problem with my code, but the output result was unexpected.

I mean,
why isn't the whole string printing out? 
Also, what is the reason for this output string?
(There seems to be no indication that this code will have 7 character,that is, "**This sp**")

Comment: Side note: The line `memset(buffer, 0, 100);` is redundant, as `fgets` will write a terminating null character into `buffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you declared `buffer` as `char *buffer`, it is not an array. Instead, it is simply a pointer.

The expression `sizeof buffer` will evaluate to the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the object that the pointer is pointing to. Since pointers typically have a size of 32 or 64 bits, the expression `sizeof buffer` will evaluate to either `4` or `8`. In your case, it seems to be `8`.

If you had declared `buffer` instead like this

```
char buffer[100];
```

then `buffer` would not be a pointer, but an array, and the expression `sizeof buffer` would have evaluated to `100`.

In your case, there is nothing wrong with using `malloc`, instead of an array. However, if you use `malloc`, you must remember the size of the allocated memory yourself. You cannot use the `sizeof` operator for this.

Instead of writing the number `100` in several places in your code, you can use a preprocessor macro for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALLOCATION_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    char *buffer = malloc( ALLOCATION_SIZE );
    memset(buffer, 0, ALLOCATION_SIZE );

    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");

    fgets(buffer, ALLOCATION_SIZE, fp);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    fclose(fp);

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This has the advantage that if you ever decide to change the number `100` to some other number, you only have to change the number in one place in your code, instead of several places.

Comment: ohh thanks a lot !!!! Btw, is there any way to know the size of the allocated memory while executing program without using that way or remembering?

Comment: @yJ.: That is not possible in ISO C (i.e. the common standard). However, individual operating systems may provide a way to do this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281686/12149471) for further information. But I do not recommend doing this, except maybe as an academic exercise. It is generally easier to simply remember the size of the allocation, for example by storing it into a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Your buffer is declared as a `char*` and not a fixed size array so `sizeof(buffer)` is 8, hence the 7 characters (plus a `'\0'`) being read and printed. `sizeof` doesn't know how many bytes you asked to `malloc` anyway. I think this is the most confusing thing when you start learning about pointers and realizing arrays work like pointers but not quite.

Solution :

```
fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
```

Or

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) fp);
```