# Why does the freed memory is less than allocated memory when overloading new and delete operators?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I created a class and overloaded `new` and `delete` operators to print the size of memory allocated/freed. In the example below, it allocated 28 bytes but frees 4 bytes. Why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    Person() {
        cout << "Constructor is called.\n";
    }

    Person(string name, int age) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size) {
        void* p = malloc(size);
        cout << "Allocate " << size << " bytes.\n";
        return p;
    }

    void operator delete(void* p) {
        free(p);
        cout << "Free " << sizeof(p) << " bytes.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person* p = new Person("John", 19);
    delete p;
}
```

output:

```
Allocate 28 bytes.
Free 4 bytes.
```

Comment: In the delete overload, you are printing out sizeof() on a void pointer, which is why you are getting a size = 4 bytes

Comment: Newbies often think `sizeof` has magical powers.

Comment: Change the code to `cout << "Allocate " << sizeof(p) << " bytes.\n";` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [Determine size of dynamically allocated memory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281686/580083)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(p)` is the size of `void*`, the size of a pointer to `void`. It is not the size of the block of memory to which this pointer is pointing, that is `sizeof(Person)`.

A `void*` alone carries no information on the size of the pointee. Though, in the background `free` "knows" how big is the memory block associated with `p` because you specified the size when you used `malloc`. If you would implement your own memory managment rather than falling back to `free`/`malloc` (eg you could use a memory pool that uses some big block of preallocated memory) then you would need to implement such mapping from pointer to size of the memory block as well.

Answer (score 0):

when you print out the size of the p which is a void pointer it contains an address which is freed and the address is exactly 4 bytes long.