# Find out how much heap memory is being used by functions in C program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am making a video game in C and somewhere in my large library I am dynamically allocating memory that is causing my whole system to crash. The dynamic memory is mostly for dynamic linked lists. There are a lot of places I am doing this and valgrind cannot find any memory leaks. Even still, as the program runs it eats up more and more RAM until it crashes my whole system.

I am using these flags with valgrind

```
./valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes ./a.out
```

I suppose everything gets cleaned up at the end, but my RAM is getting eaten up by running the  game and eventually it crashes my system. I have been looking through the code itself to no avail.

I am wondering if there is a program I could be using to run my game and in real time get information about dynamically allocated memory, specifically itd be nice if I could get the names of functions dynamically allocating the memory.

Comment: You have to keep track of memory on your own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c/1281721#1281721

Comment: This does not particularly help me, because I am not sure which part of the program is allocating the memory or where that is happening. I am looking for something like valgrind that can be used to run the program and get information about tis call stack and when it is allocating dynamic memory. Or just what is using up the memory because I do not know for sure it is the heap

Comment: You could use glibc's `mtrace()` function. When the system crashes (or you kill the program before it crashes), hopefully enough of the trace file will be valid for debugging purposes.