# Finding the size assigned by the malloc function

Tags: c, memory, integer, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any function to query the size of an allocated block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428679/any-function-to-query-the-size-of-an-allocated-block)
>   [Getting the size of a malloc only with the returned pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131925/getting-the-size-of-a-malloc-only-with-the-returned-pointer)

Let us say that I let the user specify the number of bytes to be passed to an int *x using the malloc function.  Is there a way to determine the actual number of bytes that were assigned to the integer?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428679/any-function-to-query-the-size-of-an-allocated-block?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no portable way. The language standard doesn't provide any means to do that.

Each implementation needs to keep track of the sizes of the `malloc`ed memory of course somehow, to be able to correctly `free` it, so it may offer a means to get at that information. In glibc's `malloc.h`, there is a prototype

```
size_t malloc_usable_size(void *);
```

that allows you to get at the number of usable bytes allocated for the passed-in pointer, but that is often larger than the number of bytes requested in the `malloc` call. Other implementations may offer other means to get at that kind of information.