# Get the amount of memory allocated by malloc

Tags: c, malloc

Is there an easy way to know the total amount of memory that has been allocated by every malloc in the program?
I'm suffering from a memory leak and I want to find out where it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208644/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-memory-block-allocated-using-malloc

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in a standard, operating system neutral, fashion.

But with GNU Glibc you have [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html)

On Linux systems, you can learn about your virtual memory map thru the `/proc/self/maps` (or `/proc/self/smaps` which gives more details) pseudo-file. For process of pid 123 you can read `/proc/123/maps`

Of course, details are system specific.

To find a memory leak, use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2):

By a *specific* `malloc`, yes, you have as much memory as you asked for and no more :-)

In reality, it may *give* you a little more (many implementations will give you a multiple of 16 or 32 bytes) but there's no way to tell in standard C how much. Using more than you asked for is undefined behaviour, no matter what sort of padding goes on.

Some systems have a `mallinfo` function which you can call to get statistics on the overall memory arena, if you want to know how much memory in total has been allocated. You could look into that but, again, it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard method to do so.  Microsoft's C library has a [_heapwalk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0c183dk.aspx) function that you could use to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated the memory in the first place, just make a note of how much. Perhaps use a struct to store both the pointer and the size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `valgrind` to help in debugging a potential memory leak.

In you want to do some C debugging, `glibc` has some functions to help you in debugging with `malloc`.

**Hooks for malloc**

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

**Heap Consistency Checking**

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html

**Statistics for Memory Allocation with malloc**

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html