# How to utilize sizeof() to return the size of malloc buffer allocation

Tags: c

If I allocate:

```
int *d =  malloc(5* sizeof(int));
printf("%d", (int) sizeof(d));
```

I get a value of 8 instead 5. I know `sizeof()` is not meant to return the length in this case but I wonder if there is a workaround for that since I want to avoid tracking the size manually ( by parameter passing).

Comment: `d` is a pointer and you are getting its size. That's Why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639666/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-allocated-c-buffer

Comment: "How to utilize sizeof()...". There's no such "how". There no way to use `sizeof` for that purpose.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a Function its an Operator.

Comment: You know the size. You just ***told*** it what to allocate. But you failed to check the returned pointer is not `NULL`. If it is, 0 bytes were allocated. Else, it allocated the `5* sizeof(int)` bytes you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `sizeof` operator is applied to a pointer, it gives the size of the pointer itself.  It does **not** give the size of the array it may be pointing to.

When dynamically allocating an array, you need to manually keep track of how many elements you've allocated.

Comment: `When a pointer is passed to sizeof` Sounds like `sizeof` is a function :D

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(d)` gives the size of the pointer, `d`.    A value of `8` is consistent with a 64-bit host system.

This is distinct from the allocated size of whatever `d` points at.

Since `malloc()` allocates at run time (the length to be allocated is specified when the program is run) and `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, it is not possible to use `sizeof` to obtain the length.

You need to track the size manually, in a separate variable.

```
  size_t allocated_size = 5*sizeof int;
  int *d = malloc(allocated_size);
  printf("%d", (int) allocated_size);
```

It is more common to track the number of elements (i.e. take account of the type of `d`).

```
  size_t allocated_ints = 5;
  int *d = malloc(allocated_ints * sizeof (*d));
  printf("%d", (int) allocated_ints);   // prints number of `int`
```

`size_t` is defined in `<stdlib.h>` (among others).   In C99 and later, the format specifier for printing a `size_t` is `%zu` (rather than converting to `int` and using `%d` as you have done).

Comment: Nice Answer :).

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` cannot provide the information you want. You *have* to keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

C does not track the size of an allocated buffer for you.  You must track the size manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should first decide how much memory you're going to allocate, then keep track of it in a constant or a variable.

```
const size_t sz = 5 * sizeof(int);
```