# C++ simple malloc and sizeof

Tags: c++, malloc, sizeof

I am getting a weird result with these 2 simple lines

```
char* reverse = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*19);
cout << sizeof(reverse)/sizeof(char) << endl;
```

No matter what number i put in the first line (in this example, it is 19). I always get 4 as the output. What is wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: ***What is wrong ?*** You are calculating the size of a pointer.

Comment: `char*` and `char[19]` are different types. `sizeof(char*)` is four bytes in your system

Comment: `sizeof(reverse)` doesn't do what you think it does:

Comment: So how to calculate the size of the whole block ?

Comment: Don't.  Use `std::string` if you want dynamic character arrays.  That has a `size` function.

Comment: I am re-implementing several string methods for learning. The duplicate notice explains the other direction. This explains why sizeof function is an exception
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671790/how-does-sizeofarray-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **32-bit machine** sizeof pointer is 32 bits (4 bytes), while on **64 bit machine** it's 8 bytes. Regardless of what data type they are pointing to, they have fixed size.

And

```
sizeof(char) = 1 byte
```

So, you are getting 4 every time because your system is a **32-bit machine**.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you explained how to do what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: I think there is no way to recalculate the size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639666/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-allocated-c-buffer

Comment: I agree with both of you. I answered why OP is getting 4 every time and i guess there is no straight forward approach to get the actual size from the pointer (not 100% sure though). If anyone knows that, you can tell me how to do that or you can edit my answer. Thanks :)