# Dynamic Memory Allocation in C using malloc and realloc

Tags: c

why the ptr have the same size even tho I was expecting the size of ptr to be 5*size(int)/4 = 20 but I got the current size is 8 and also the new size is 8, any explanation pls?

```
 int *ptr;

 ptr = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
 printf("current size is %ld\n", sizeof(ptr));

 for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
 {
     ptr[i] = i + 1;
 }
    
 for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
 {
     printf("%d\n",*(ptr + i));
 }
  
 ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));

 printf("new size is %ld\n", sizeof(ptr));
   
 for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
 {
     printf("%d\n", *(ptr + i));
 }
```

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)` gives the size of the pointer (which is fixed) and not the size of what it points to. You need to track the size yourself.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: if a allocate 5*size(int) to ptr, do I give to ptr 20 addresses to work on? and how the pointer keeps tracking the addresses given, coz the addresses can't be like *****1,*****2,*****3,... so they gonna be in different places on the memory or am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any pointer on a 64-bit PC will *probably* be 64 bits, or 8 bytes. You're printing the size of the pointer itself, not the entire block of memory it points to.

See the article @kaylum pointed to in comments. [How to determine the size of an allocated C buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639666/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-allocated-c-buffer)

Comment: Re “Any pointer on a 64-bit PC will be 64 bits, or 8 bytes”: The size of a pointer is determined by the C implementation, not the system. I have worked on a C implementation that used 32-bit pointers on a 64-bit architecture, because it was designed to save space in applications that used large numbers of pointers but did not need more than 2^32 bytes of memory. A C implementation might also use pointers larger than the address space requires, to provide additional features such as authentication or bug detection.

Comment: Edited to account for 64-bit pointers being the _probable_ pointer size on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're attempting will work with stack-allocated arrays, but not with heap-allocated pointers.

[comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 7.27](http://c-faq.com/malloc/querysize.html) -

Q. *So can I query the `malloc` package to find out how big an allocated block is?*

A. *Unfortunately, there is no standard or portable way. (Some compilers provide nonstandard extensions.) **If you need to know, you'll have to keep track of it yourself.** (See also question [7.28](http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html).)*