# Get size of dynamic pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write a dynamic pointer to a file in C++.

This is my declaration in header file:

```
byte* buffer;
```

Then in Cpp file, I allocated it:

```
buffer = new byte[1000];
```

However the size will be bigger than 1000 in dynamic allocation.

Then I write to the file:

ofstream myfile;

```
myfile.open("test.txt", ios::binary);
myfile.write((char*)buffer, 1000);  
myfile.close();
```

If I specify the length of buffer to 1000, then the rest of bytes after 1000 will be discarded. If I use: sizeof(buffer) then it is only 1 byte written.

How can I get the dynamic size of the buffer?

Comment: that's not C++ _style_, and in general it is not possible to get the size of an array from a pointer to an element of it.

Comment: global variable, `new[]`, `MAGIC_BUFFER_SIZE` needless cast?

Comment: @sehe then how can I achieve it better>

Comment: @olidev: It's where your code has a number with no apparent meaning or derivation. When you say "1000", why 1000? Why not 1001? How did you arrive at that number? What does it mean? If I change it to 1001 what will break?

Comment: @olidev You already have that answer.

Comment: @DeadMG then when I change it to a smaller number, example: 100 then I got a problem with memory allocation.

Comment: @DeadMG I am C# and Java programmer, I am doing some conversion from C# to C++ and facing these problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get array size for dynamic created memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688148/how-to-get-array-size-for-dynamic-created-memory)

Comment: @olidev: You shouldn't try to guess the size of the buffer by trial and error. Instead, when using `buffer[x]`, make sure that `buffer.size()` is _at least_ `x+1`. You can call `buffer.resize` as often as you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple:

```
std::vector<byte> buffer;
buffer.resize(1000);
myfile.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

Comment: If the cast to `char*` was needed in the questioner's code, then it's needed in yours too: `byte` is probably `unsigned char`.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<byte> buffer(1000);`.

Comment: @Nawaz: my reading of the problem suggested that the definition and the sizing of `buffer` happened in different places. If you can combine them, you indeed should.

Comment: Maybe we should have a C++ FAQ question, "should I just use a freaking vector?", that we can dupe these questions to :-) Then someone can answer it "no, use `deque`".

Comment: but when the size of the buffer is larger than 1000 by passing to reference. when i call it buffer.size(), i still get 1000

Comment: @olidev: vectors have whatever size they've been resized to (including indirectly resized, via inserts and erases). If `buffer.size()` returns 1000, then the size of the vector is 1000, it is not "larger than 1000". Maybe you need to ask another question about the vector code that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the buffer is 1000. It's true that when you use "new" it sometimes can allocate more memory but this is done in order to fasten the next "new". so every other memory that was allocated after the 1000 first bytes may and probably will be used in future "new"s.
bottom line you can't and should assume you have any more then 1000 bytes.

Comment: _`However the size will be bigger than 1000 in dynamic allocation.`_

Comment: A. it `may` be bigger. B. I can't think of any reason you would like to do that. C. even if it was possible you would only have junk there.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The '1000' is just a sample, real code will get a char* that points to dynamically allocated array, is my interpretation. Yes, the question wording is crummy

Comment: I probably am missing the point. lets say he asked for 1000 but the `new` actually requested 4096 bytes from the OS. what he want to do with it? the memory management can give the rest of the 3096 bytes to who over it wishes.

Comment: The point is, `new byte[1000]` is _not in his code_, it is somewhere in the caller and the size isn't known. Hint `byte` smells Java/C# and there you you could e.g. just say `buffer.Length`.

Comment: Are you referring to `new byte[1000]` potentially allocating more than just 1000 elements? That's true, but also ludicrous. I prefer to assume the OP is sane. This sentence from the Q just about sums it up _`"If I use: sizeof(buffer) then it is only 1 byte written"`_. Add to that [I am C# and Java programmer _(22 hrs ago)_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699326/get-size-of-dynamic-pointer-c/10699388#comment13890208_10699326) and you'll realize that there is really no debate as to what he meant.