# Finding the Size of the Dynamically Allocated Array

Tags: c++, memory-management

A simple question, though I cant find an anwer in the quicker time.

I am using the Dynamic allocation through 'new' keyword for the allocation of chunck of memory for an array, as

```
int *array = new int[size]; //The Size is got by some logic
```

And now on the long run of the logic, I need to parse this array such that i need to get/calculate the size of this array.

I am clueless at here. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking for. How to calculate the value of size? That depends on us having a lot more context.

Comment: I am looking for some logic or a way around to get the size of the array, no of elements it can accomodate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to determine the size of a C++ array programmatically? And if not, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-no)

Answer (score 8):

You need to keep the allocation size in a separate variable to know what it was after you're done with the `new`.

On the bright side - C++ offers you a tool called `std::vector` that would solve the problem for you without using `new` and keeping the size (and without being restricted by the size, as well).

So if you need to preallocate the size you can use:

```
vector<int> array(size);
```

But normally you'd just declare

```
vector<int> array;
```

and then go on and fill it, and query `array.size()` to know how many items there are.