# Is there any way to get the length of an dynamically allocated array in C++?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to determine the size of a C++ array programmatically? And if not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-no)

Can I get the length of a dynamically allocated array in C++, if not, how does C++'s delete operator know how many elements to free. 
I searched the forum and found that for dynamically allocated arrays, the length are stored in the four bytes before the array's header or somewhere else. How can I get this value?

Comment: @larsmans Yes, you are right. I will refer to the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

The four bytes before the header are definitely an implementation detail you shouldn't use. If you need to know the size of your array, use a std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. This is implementation defined, so you cannot access it. You can (and have to), however, store it in a variable, or use some types that control the size, such as `std::vector`, `std::string`, etc.

The `delete[]` operator knows because the implementation of the C++ library has that information, but it is not available to the C++ program. In some implementations, that's the case, it is stored in some bytes before the actual address of the pointer, but again, you cannot know it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it is so, then how does the compiler know this value to do delete []? If the compiler can access this value, why does the compiler hide this value from users?

Comment: It is not the compiler, but the library. It is hidden in the code of  `delete[]`, the same way you hide, say, the `private` variables in your classes. Summary: you cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. However, `std::vector<T> v(N)` is almost exactly the same thing as `new T[N]` and offers `v.size()`, so you should really be using that, unless you have a terrific reason why you want to use the manual array.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define your own allocator (overloading operator new[] and delete[] for whatever class you care about or doing *#define malloc mymalloc* and *#define free myfree* depending on your situation). Where you store your array length is up to you but generally one would allocate extra bytes (whatever amount is the proper amount for memory alignment - generally 4, 8, or 16) before the beginning of the array and store the length there.