# Should I use delete or delete[] when receiving either a dynamic array or heap object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Say I have two items on the heap:

```
Foo *f = new Foo;
Foo *g = new Foo[42];
```

And say I have a function that receives a `Foo` pointer and within the function it needs to perform a `delete`:

```
void bar(Foo *p) {
    // some stuff
    delete p;
}
```

This function might be called like so:

```
bar(f); // passing a pointer to a Foo object on the heap
bar(g); // passing a pointer to an array on the heap
```

I recognize that `delete[]` and `delete` should be used to free memory allocated with `new[]` and `new` respectively; However since the function doesn't know if its parameter `p` was allocated with `new` or `new[]`, how can this function properly `delete` or `delete[]`?

Comment: The goal of modern C++ is to never have to write `delete`. Use smart pointers, vectors, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (portably) detect that and do the right thing in the function.

A "workaround" would be to use `std::vector<Foo>` instead of the array, and just always use `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a problem with the Single Responsibility Principle.

You have some amount of processing that operates on a single object, so it's reasonable to pass an individual object or an array.  (Why isn't that processing also useful for an array element other than the first, or a non-dynamic object?)

And then you have to free the object.  Or the array.

There are three different tasks here, which calls for three different functions.

Essentially, if "the function doesn't know if its parameter `p` was allocated with `new` or `new[]`", that function has no business trying to deallocate.  What if the parameter is on the stack?  What if a pooled allocator was used?

Also, once the processing is moved to a separate function, it becomes easy to make a function for "process then delete single object" and also "process then delete array" without duplication (both call the helper function for the processing component).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1.** From a code design point of view, you should probably avoid cases like this altogether, and have the object be deleted by the same class, pair of create-destroy functions, or code block that allocated it. This way, you know you're not making any mistakes.

**Solution 2.** If you compiler supports them, use `std::shared_ptr` and lambda functions, and use a different deallocator for each pointer, as appropriate. Read about shared pointers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo[20], [](Foo* p) { delete[] p; });
std::shared_ptr<Foo> g(new Foo);
```

The first one, `f` is a shared pointer to an array. When I create it, I give as the first parameter a (normal) pointer to the array; the second parameter is a *lambda function* that takes a `Foo* p` parameter and its body is `{ delete[] p; }`.

By default, `std::shared_ptr` uses `delete` to deallocate memory. This is why, when I create the second one, I only give it the pointer to the object and don't specify any custom deallocator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You never know if a pointer points to an object or an array of such object.

But, if you really want to have a single function for deallocation, and **if you can ever ever remember to allocate anything like an array** even if you're allocating one object, the following use is legal:

```
Foo *h = new Foo[0];
Foo *f = new Foo[1];
Foo *g = new Foo[42];

void bar(Foo *p) {
    // some stuff
    delete [] p;
}
```

However, remember that sometimes technically possible doesn't mean that you should use it. That depends on your use case whether it makes sense to treat an object as a special case of an array.

The more elegant C++ way is to use `std::vector` or `boost::scoped_ptr`, `boost::scoped_array`, etc, which guarantee to call correct version of `delete` operator, just as their names indicate.

Comment: This is not really a good suggestion. Sure, it's a possibility but it creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass which it is.  The function can't determine that at runtime.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-n) for a good explanation.

Comment: How, exactly, would one "pass which it is" ?

Comment: I guess I'm assuming you know which one you're passing in.  If you' don't know that then it's not possible to determine it.

Answer (score -2):

It's up to the compiler vendor to decide how this should be implemented, and as such falls under the "magic" category.

In general though, the runtime will allocate an extra additional 4 bytes when you use new[]. Then it will store the size of the array in these bytes, and return the allocation + 4 bytes. When deallocating, it will remove 4 from the pointer you passed it, read the size and use that to decide how many destructors etc. to call.

You can read more about this in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14)

Comment: There's no such thing as magic. The answer here isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: This is not guaranteed by the language standard. You shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: If the program in question doesn't need to be portable, then relying on a specific C++ implementation is a valid thing to do.  One just needs to understand and accept the implications going in.