# C++ programming, dynamical memory is not working properly using malloc and calloc

Tags: c++, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I have just started learning C++ and I came on a problem I couldn't find on the Internet so I hope you can help me with.

This is my code:

```
int* a;
int* b;

a = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
b = (int*)calloc(5, sizeof(int));

cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
cout << sizeof(b) << endl;
```

What compiler returns me is: 8, 8.
If I use:

```
cout << sizeof(*a) << endl;
cout << sizeof(*b) << endl;
```

Compiler returns 4, 4.

The same thing is with malloc. I am using .

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the size of b 20 as it is 5 times bigger if int is 4 bytes long?

Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size of an object. The object in this case is a pointer. What the pointer points at is not included or known.

Comment: `sizeof()` is a compile time constant in `c++`

Comment: Ahaaaa. Can you tell me, how would you check if memory allocation was successful? For example, if I said: malloc(5*sizeof(int)), how do I know it has 4*5 = 20 bytes allocated? Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the size of an array from a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: These `c` functions return a null pointer if not successful.

Comment: And if you want a strict C++ dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically

Comment: With `malloc` check for `NULL` (or `nullptr` if you got 'em). If you used `new` typically an exception is thrown on failure. But what you should really be using is a [Library Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). They manage the memory for you and know everything you need to know about the contents.

Comment: why not `std::vector<int> a(5,0);` ?

Comment: `std::vector<int> a(1);` builds a 1 element dynamic array and sets the `int` to 0. Call `a.size()` and you'll get 1 for 1 element. It's almost foolproof.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't read about vectors yet, so I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(*a)` and `sizeof(*b)` are always going to be equal to 4. It seems you expect them to return the size of arrays, but you need to understand that `a` and `b` are **not** arrays. They are pointers to `int`. If `sizeof(int)` is 4, then `sizeof(*a)` is also going to be 4, and this is already known at compile time.

With that being said, you do not need to use the C library functions `malloc()` and `calloc()` in C++. If you need manual memory allocation, use `new` and `delete`:

```
a = new int;
b = new int[5];
```

If you need to do zero-initialization like `calloc` does, just use `()` to default-construct the allocated integers:

```
a = new int();
b = new int[5]();
```

Instead of `free()`, use `delete` or `delete[]`, depending on how `new` was called previously:

```
delete a;    // Note: no '[]'
delete[] b;  // Needs '[]'
```

However, you do not need manual memory allocation here. Just use `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <vector>
// ...

std::vector<int> a(5); // 5 int elements, zero-initialized.
std::cout << a.size() << '\n'; // Will print '5'.
```

As a rule of thumb, your C++ code should not have any calls to `new`, `delete`, `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `free()`. Doing manual memory management requires more code and is error-prone. Use containers like `vector` and smart pointers like `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` instead to reduce the chance of memory and other resource leaks. These safer types are also more convenient. With `vector` for example, you do not have to remember the size of your allocated memory yourself. The `vector` keeps track of its size for you. You can also copy vectors easily by just assigning them directly. You also don't need to `delete` or `free()` vectors manually. They are automatically deleted when they go out of scope.

As a side-note, I recommend getting rid of the habit of using `endl` for printing newlines. `endl` flushes the stream, it doesn't just print a newline. If you use it, you will be constantly flushing the output stream, which is a slow operation. You only rarely need to flush a stream, in which case you can just do so manually with `<< flush` if the need ever arises.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! :)

I will correct all things you've noted! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the sizeof a pointer in the first case and the size of the element int the second. *a is for your intents and purposes the same as a[0]. The size of the pointer is architecture dependent, and the size of the int is 4.

The sizeof value is evaluated at compile time. Dynamic memory allocation occurs at runtime. To find out the amount allocated at run time you can look at overloading the new operator (not recommended) or using the containers as the comments have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)` is the size of the pointer (this is 8 in a 64bit architecture normally), while `sizeof(*a)`  is the size of the pointed to element (an integer value).  Nothing returned by `sizeof` operator has dynamic nature (as the number of elements returned by `calloc(3)`)

By the way, `calloc()` is strongly deprecated in C++.  Its use is reserved to cases in which you have to pass the pointers to C code and for legacy code.  Use the operators `new` and `new []` (the last one in this case).  But none of these will change things, the `sizeof` operator will continue returning the values you got.  If you want to check the size of the returned array, then check the parameters passed to both operators.