# how to get a length of char array char*

Tags: c++, arrays, char, sizeof, size-t

i have something like this
`char * array[] = {"one","two","three","five"};`
how can I get its length (which is 3 here).
if I use `strlen()` then I get the length of "one".

Comment: What does "length" mean, for an array of pointers, and how did you arrive at the conclusion that this array's "length" is 3? I count four pointers in this array. Furthermore, this is not even valid C++, since in C++ string literals are constant, and every self-respecting C++ compiler will refuse to compile the shown code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the size of a C++ array programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically)

Comment: Be careful. Once you pass array to a function it will decay to a pointer and the size information will be lost inside the function. This is one reason to use std::array<> or std::vector<> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you have to use the qualifier const in the array declaration.

```
const char * array[] = {"one","two","three","five"};
```

To get the number of elements in the array you can write

```
size_t n = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
```

If your compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then you also can write

```
#include <iterator>

//...

size_t n = std::size( array );
```

Before the C++ 17 Standard you can use the structure `std::extent`.

For example

```
#include <type_trats>

//...

size_t n = std::extent<decltype( array )>::value;
```

Answer (score 0):

with c++17 : the [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) in the iterator header:

> Return value :
>
> The size of c or array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { -5, 10, 15 };
    std::cout << std::size(arr) << '\n';
    ...
```