# Is this possible that new without bracket but delete with bracket in C++

Tags: c++

I know that to create array in C++
use new [] 
and delete this array
use delete []

I wonder if I create a object
and delete this with delete []

```
Test * a = new Test;
delete [] a;
```

Well... it works...
but is it safe? should I use delete without bracket?

Comment: When you say it "works", what does that mean? What behavior do you think constitutes working?

Comment: Hmm, how to find the questions this is a dupe of....

Comment: Somebody use [the question qeadz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array-c) found (see answer [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418295/is-this-possible-that-new-without-bracket-but-delete-with-bracket-in-c#comment35886954_23418318)) as dupe target as well, so both get shown.

Comment: If Richard's answer covers it, you should select it as your chosen answer *nudge nudge*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not ok. Behaviour will be at best undefined.

edit:

Info link added by popular request: http://web.archive.org/web/20080703153358/http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/01/03/attacking-delete-and-delete-in-c

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array-c

Comment: @qeadz: Great article linked from the comments there, too.

Comment: @Richard sorry I replied in the wrong place. this was meant to be to the question :/ anyway Ben is right that the article is really good. Perhaps add it to your answer if you care since it's a great explanation.
http://web.archive.org/web/20080703153358/http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/01/03/attacking-delete-and-delete-in-c

Comment: info link added as requested.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaiviour and best avoided.
IIRC MSVC handles (or at least used to handle ) new and array new identically which is (or was) a delightful source of migration headaches ;-)

Comment: They can be handled the same for primitive types, but never for types with a non-trivial destructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I seem to recall MSVC managing it for non-trivial UDTs. I suspect it did so by having array delete complexity for non-array delete (i.e. implementing them both the same way). I've no idea whether it's still that bad.

Comment: It's not allowed for non-array `new` to work like array `new` (storing the count).  non-array `new` has zero storage overhead (in terms of the size of the block requested from `::operator new`), mandated by the Standard.

Comment: @BenVoigt: MSVC played pretty fast and loose with what was allowed ;-)