# Deleting an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's suppose the following code:

```
    int* ptr = new int[10];
    ...
    ...
    ptr += 2;
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
```

Should ptr be pointing on the first element of the array when the delete is called?

Comment: `delete` what you `new`. Nothing else.

Comment: Are you facing any actual problems with your code? If so elaborate in your question, if not you're off-topic here :-/ ...

Comment: '_Should ptr be pointing on the first element of the array when the delete is called?_' Certainly, YES!

Comment: Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array-c for more info.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the question's not off topic... the "actual problem" is obviously knowing whether the code has defined behaviour, deleting the array as clearly intended.  It's probably a duplicate and could have been resolved by a quick look at the Standard or many online references, but that's not unique to this question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `delete` on something that you didn't get back from `new`, that's **undefined behavior**.

So the result of the following code is undefined:

```
int* ptr = new int[10];
ptr += 2;
delete[] ptr;
```

Let's look at the standard as well:

> #### C++ 2011. Section 3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions. Paragraph 3.
>
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to `operator delete(void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library, and the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to `operator delete[](void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](std::size_t)` or `operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library.