# Deallocator of arrays in c++ after modification of pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

Here is the code

```
int *p = new int[10];
...
delete[] p;
```

How does the program know how many elements were there when delete[] was called?

Suppose we inserted the following code in between:

```
p++;
```

Will the program try to free one more element? Will it just stop at the 10th element?

Comment: You would have Undefined Behavior, as `p` is no longer a pointer that was returned by `new[]`.  It would be *bad*.

Comment: It's implementation defined, but usually a secret integer is stored just before the array in memory that contains its size.

Comment: and closely related to *both* questions, [How does `delete[]` know it's an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocator keeps one track of of how much memory you are allocating. This is usually stored in a "head" segment just before the memory that you are allocating. When you execute delete[], the de-allocator knows exactly how much memory to free.

If you modify the pointer, you would have a undefined behavior.