# Confusion about delete operator in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, delete-operator

This looks simple question but my friend debated with me that below program invokes UB. But I think he is incorrect.
Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int* p=new int[3]();
    int* q=p;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        std::cout<<q[i]<<' ';
    delete[] q;
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
```

Is this program's behavior well defined? What happen if I write **delete[] p;** instead of **delete[] q;** ? Is it valid?

Comment: Why would there be any UB here?

Comment: Note: delete does not delete a pointer, but the object (memory) the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/703691/1492578) will help.

Comment: @PravasiMeet I wanted to know why you thought there might be UB. Generally if you think something is wrong, you have a reason to. I wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the program is well defined.  First you create a pointer assigned to newly allocated memory.

```
int* p=new int[3]();
```

Then you create another pointer pointing to that memory

```
int* q=p;
```

You then use that pointer to assign data into that memory.  After that you delete memory which is pointer to `q` which is the same as `p` which is okay.  The program returns and all is well

`delete` doesn't care about what variable you use.  What is important is that the memory that the pointer points to was created with `new` and that you only call delete once on the memory.

Comment: @PravasiMeet Yes.  as long as the pointer points to memory that was allocated with `new` it will be safe.  Don't call `delete` on both variables though as that is undefined behavior.  I would also suggest you use smart pointers and then you don;t have to worry about these things.

Comment: Just as a further comment: If it worked the way your friend suggests, where you must delete from the "original" variable, then many standard library containers would be impossible, and for instance lots of code that uses std::unique_ptr would be UB. Any code that looks like this for instance: `X * x = new X(); if(x->is_good()) { ptr.reset(x); } else { dispose_of(x); }`

Answer (score 2):

The pointer returned by the `new[]` operator is not the start of the allocated memory but rather points to the first object (or the object at index 0). Now, [based on the compiler you're using](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array), the run-time system stores the number of objects, n, somewhere where it can be retrieved if you only know the memory location pointed by `p`.

[According to this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx), the deletion of a vector performs this operation in reverse:

> When you do "delete[] p", you are saying, "p points to a bunch of
>   objects, but I'm not telling you how many." In this case, the compiler
>   needs to generate extra code to keep track of how many it needs to
>   destruct. This extra information is kept in a "secret place" when the
>   vector is allocated with "new[]".

Since doing `int *q = p` essentially points to the same array's 0th object, it is equivalent to call `delete[] q` and `delete[] p`.

Answer (score 1):

No UB. It will work fine. Not much to add here.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `delete` can be applied ONLY to memory (i.e. address) that was allocated with operator `new`. If you allocate once you should free (detele) also once, does not metter which pointer (variable storing address) is used, so your code is valid.

But, remember, after you `delete[] q` neither `q` nor `p` DO NOT have to be used. The best way is assigne `NULL` to both pointers.