# How do I initialize the size of an array of pointers in a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, nodes

I've tried two different things, but I'm not entirely sure what is happening. Looking for an explanation and input on how to do this in the best possible way, thanks! I don't want to use a vector.

Graph.h

```
public:
   void setNodeList(int num);
private:
   Node *nodeList[];
```

Graph.cpp

```
void Graph::setNodeList(int num)
{
   nodeList[num]; // Would this work?
   *nodeList = new Node[num]; // Or this? Not really sure.
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your array is situated on the heap ("permanently" stored, and removed after the methods returns), then you should use

```
*nodeList = new Node[num];
```

Be aware to delete your allocated memory via `delete[] nodeList` and NOT via `delete nodeList` (without `[]`). This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array) explains why.

As @StoryTeller suggests I would also check the STL `std::vector`, which represents a dynamic collection.