# delete & new in c++

Tags: c++

This may be very simple question,But please help me.

i wanted to know what exactly happens when i call new & delete , For example in below code

```
char * ptr=new char [10];

delete [] ptr;
```

call to new returns me memory address. Does it allocate exact 10 bytes on heap, Where information about size is stored.When i call delete on same pointer,i see in debugger that there are a lot of byte get changed before and after  the 10 Bytes.

Is there any header for each new which contain information about number of byte allocated by new.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327848/how-does-the-delete-in-c-know-how-many-memory-locations-to-delete

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do it allocate exact 10 bytes

That's implementation dependant. The guarantee is "**at least** 10 chars".

> Where information about size is stored?

That's implementation dependant.

> Is there any header for each new which contain information about number of byte allocated by new?

That's implementation dependant.

By "that's implementation dependant" I mean it's not defined in the standard.

Answer (score 5):

That's all up to the compiler and your runtime library. It's only exactly defined what effects `new` and `delete` have on your program, but how exactly these are acieved is not specified.

In your case it seems like a little more memory than requested is allocated and it will probably store management information like the size of the current chunk of memory, information about adjacent areas of free space or information to help the debugger try to detect buffer overflows and similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

It is completely implementation-dependent. In general case you have to store the number of elements elsewhere. The implementation must allocate enough space for at least the number of elements specified, but it can allocate more.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any header for each new which contain information about number of byte allocated by new.

That's platform dependent but yes, on many platforms there are.

Answer (score 2):

Precisely, according to the standard, `new char[10]` will alloc **at least** 10 bytes in the heap.

The internals of `new` and `delete` are implementation dependent. So it will vary from compiler to compiler, and platform to platform. Additionally, you can find a variety of allocator algorithms (e.g: [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)).

I'll give you an overview of how it **could** work internally, but don't take it as absolute truth. It's written for the solely purpose of this explanation.

In short, the `new` operator internally invokes `malloc`. The `malloc` uses a really long linked list of available memory blocks, aka `free chain`. When `malloc` is invoked, it lookups this list for the first block that's big enough to hold the requested size. After that, it splits the block in two parts, one with the size you requested, and the other with the rest, which is then added back to the free chain. Finally, it returns the block with the request size.

The inverse occurs in a `free` call, which is invoked by delete/delete[]. In short, it puts the provided block back to the `free chain`.

There could be fancy tricks during the processes I described above, like sorting the `free chain`, rounding the requested size to the next power of two to reduce memory fragmentation, and so on.

Comment: `new` doesn't need to rely on `malloc`. That's implementation dependant as well :)

Comment: @Axel correct, if I didn't make the 2nd sentence clear, let me know, so I can clarify. Or even add an extra comment before the overview. It was basically to give an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * ptr=new char [10];
```

You are creating an array of 10 character's in heap and storing the address of 0th element in a pointer.this is similar to doing an malloc in C

```
delete [] ptr;
```

You are deleting(freeing  the memory) the heap memory which was allocated by the earlier statement.this is similar to doing a free in c.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation dependent, but mostly the metadata for a block of memory is usually stored in the area before the memory address returned. The change that you observed before the 10 bytes was likely metadata being updated for this block (likely the size of the block being written into the meta data), and after the 10 bytes were metadata being updated for the next block (still unallocated, likely the pointer to the next chunk on the free list).

It is not a good idea to mess with the heap as it is not portable. However, if you want to do such heap magic, I suggest you implement your own memory pools (just get a large chunk of memory from the heap and manage it yourself). A possible place to start would be to look at [libmm](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/mm/).

Answer (score 0):

While the specifics are implementation dependent, one piece of information the implementation will need to store is the number of elements in the array. Or if it does not store it directly, it will need to accurately derive it from the block size allocated.

The reason for this because if an array of objects is allocated with new[], when they are deleted with delete[], the destructor of each object in the array will need to be called. delete[] will need to know how many objects to destruct. This is why it is necessary to match new with delete and new[] with delete[].