# delete function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

I saw an example of using the function: delete in cpp and I didn't completely understand it.
the code is:

```
class Name {
    const char* s;
    //...
};

class Table {
      Name* p;
      size_t sz;
public:
      Table(size_t s = 15){p = new Name[sz = s]; }
      ~Table { delete[] p; }
};
```

What is the exact action of the command: `delete[] p;`?

I think the aim was to delete all the pointers in the container Table.

The brackets in `delete[]` give me a clue that it deletes an array of pointers to Name but the size of the array is not specified, so how does the destructor "know" how many pointers to delete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete vs delete\[\] operators in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c) and [How does the delete in C++ know how many memory locations to delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327848/how-does-the-delete-in-c-know-how-many-memory-locations-to-delete)

Comment: "all the pointers" - note that `Table` only contains a single pointer. It is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of `Name`, but there is only one dynamically created object (the array) that needs to be deallocated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`delete` isn't a function, it's an operator.

A `delete` expression using `[]` destroys objects created with `new ... []` and releases the associated memory. `delete[]` must be used for pointers returned by `new ... []`; non-array `delete` only on pointers returned by non-array `new`. Using the non-matching `delete` form is always incorrect.

The `delete` expression in `~Table()` (missing `()` in your code) will destroy the dynamically created array of `Name` objects ensuring that the `Name` destructor is called for each member of the array.

It is up the the implementation to implement some mechanism of recording the number of elements in arrays allocated with `new ... []` the programmer doesn't have to worry about this.

In many implementations, where the array elements have non-trivial destructors, a `new[]` expression will allocate extra space to record the element count before the space for all the array members. This hidden count is then looked up when `delete[]` is used to ensure the correct number of destructors are called. This is just an implementation detail, though, other implementations are possible.

Comment: 1) in the code many objects can be initialized with new...[]
which of them is destroyed by delete?
2)also in the example code () were missing.

Comment: @Day_Dreamer: Another way to think of it is as a single array of many objects. `new Name[sz]` allocates an array (of many objects) `delete[]` deallocates the one array (of many objects). Every member of the array is destroyed when the array is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

In short, `delete[]` knows the size of the array it is deleting because it is required to.

Because the C++ language standard states that it must know.
So when you allocate an array, it is up to the system to store the size somewhere where `delete[]` can find it.

One option is to allocate a few bytes more than needed. Use the first bytes to specify the size, and then instead of returning a pointer to the first allocated byte, return a pointer to the first byte past the size field.

Then `delete[]` just has to subtract a few bytes from the pointer in order to find the size.

Another option could be to have a global `map<void*, int>`, where the key is the pointer to a memory allocation, and the value is the size of that allocation. There are plenty of other ways in which `delete[]` can find out the size. The C++ standard doesn't specify which one to use. It just says that `delete[]` must know the size, and leaves it up to the implementers to figure out *how* to pull it off.

Comment: where is the implementation of the mechanism of the pair:delete and new?

Comment: in the runtime library, which is typically provided with the compiler.