# Something unclear with operator delete

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am new to C++ and I have something unclear:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double* foo(void)
{
    double* b = new double[100];
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    double* a = foo();

    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code? I mean whether the way I use operator delete is right? I assign the pointer b which points to the allocated memory in foo function to pointer a outside foo, can I release memory by means of delete[]a in main? I don't have any idea how does the compiler calculate the number of bytes to release when execute delete[]. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does delete\[\] "know" the size of the operand array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is correct (though not usually part of any well-written modern C++ program).

Dynamically allocated arrays are stored with hidden information about their size so that `delete[] p` knows how many elements to delete.

If you're curious about the details, you can rig up a little test class and take advantage of the member allocation operators:

```
struct ArrayMe
{
  static void * operator new[](size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
  {
    void * p = ::operator new[](n);
    std::cout << "new[]ed " << n << " bytes at " << p << "." << std::endl;
    return p;
  }

  static void operator delete[](void * p, std::size_t n) throw()
  {
    std::cout << "delete[]ing " << n << " bytes at " << p << "." << std::endl;
    ::operator delete[](p);
  }

  double q;
};
```

Now say:

```
std::cout << "sizeof(ArrayMe) = " << sizeof(ArrayMe) << std::endl;
ArrayMe * const a = new ArrayMe[10];
delete[] a;
```

Comment: “Arrays are stored with hidden information about their size” : this stands for dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: Wait!  Did you just provide code to a C++ newbie that uses an exception specification!?!  Shame on you.

Comment: @deft_code: I believe those are mandatory for the allocation operators. Or maybe that's only for the global ones, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Call delete [] to delete C-style arrays allocated with operator new [].  Delete [] will know how many bytes were allocated by operator new[].

Call delete to delete objects allocated with operator new (no brackets).  Never, ever mix them!  I.e. never call delete [] on something allocated with operator new, and never call delete on something allocated with operator new [].