# Delete on a pointer in a Union

Tags: c++, pointers

I have tried some interesting code(at least for me !). Here it is.

```
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct{
    int one;

    /*Destructor: Program crashes if the below code uncommented*/
    /*
    ~myStruct(){
        std::cout<<"des\n";
    } 
    */
};
struct finalStruct {
    int noOfChars;
    int noOfStructs;

    union { 
        myStruct *structPtr;
        char *charPtr;
    }U;

};
int main(){
    finalStruct obj;
    obj.noOfChars = 2;
    obj.noOfStructs = 1;
    int bytesToAllocate = sizeof(char)*obj.noOfChars 
                        + sizeof(myStruct)*obj.noOfStructs;

    obj.U.charPtr = new char[bytesToAllocate];
    /*Now both the pointers charPtr and structPtr points to same location*/

    delete []obj.U.structPtr;
}
```

I have allocated memory to charPtr and deleted with structPtr. It is crashing when I add a destructor to myStruct otherwise no issues.

What exactly happens here. As I know delete[] will call the destructor as many times as number given in new[]. Why it is not crashing when there is no destructor in myStruct?

Answer (score 8):

First off, storing one member of a union and then reading another in the way you're doing it is Undefined Behaviour, plain and simple. It's just wrong and anything could happen.

That aside, it's quite likely the type pun you're attempting with the union actually works (but remember it's *not* guaranteed). If that's the case, the following happens:

You allocate an array of `bytesToAllocate` objects of type `char` and store the address in the unionised pointer.

Then, you call `delete[]` on the unionised pointer *typed as `myStruct*`*. Which means that it assumes it's an array of `myStruct` objects, and it will invoke the destructor on each of these objects. However, the array does not contain any `myStruct` objects, it contains `char` objects. In fact, the size in bytes of the array is not even a multiple of the size of `myStruct`! The `delete` implementation must be thoroughly confused. It probably interprets the first `sizeof(myStruct)` bytes as one `myStruct` object and calls the destructor in those bytes. Then, there's less than `sizeof(myStruct)` bytes left, but there are still some left, so the destructor is called on those incomplete bytes, reaches beyond the array, and hilarity ensues.

Of course, since this is just UB, my guess at the behaviour above could be way off. Plain and simple, you've confused it, so it acts confused.

Comment: The memory manager is likely not confused at all. It is totally ignorant.

Comment: No. The main points of your answer are wrong, I'm afraid: No destructor is called, and free is not confused. No bytes are interpreted as anything.

Comment: @PeterSchneider The OP says "when I uncomment the dtor, it crashes." So I am commenting on the case when the dtor exists. Why would it not be called then?

Comment: Oh. Given that the OP was not wondering about the crash in the presence of a user defined dtor, I thought (seriously) we are answering the OP's question: "Why it is not crashing when there is no destructor in myStruct?", assuming you are talking about a wrongly assumed  default dtor. Your answer is valid if there is a dtor, true. Perhaps you can make that clearer. But that is clearly not what the OP was asking.

Comment: Aliasing with `char*` _is_ guaranteed, IIRC.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Where exactly? I know you can access an object as an array of `char` (or `unsigned char`), but I still think not via a pointer to such in a union.

Answer (score 2):

delete makes two things, call destructor and deallocate memory.

You allocate data for one type, but delete if faking another type.
You shouldn't do it. There are many things one could do in C/C++, take a look at [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) for more inspirations :-)

A struct in C++ without any function and having only [plain old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) is itself a POD. It never calls a constructor/destructor when created/deleted.
Even not standard c-tors/d-tors. Just for performance reasons.

A Struct having **(EDIT) user-defined copy-assignment operator, virtual** function or d-tor is internally a little bit more complicated. It has a table of member function pointers.

If you allocate the memory block with chars, this table is not initialized. When you try to delete this memory block using a not POD-type, it first calls the destructor. And as the destructor function pointer is not initialized, it calls any memory block in your memory space, thinking it was the function. That's why it crashes.

Comment: Are you sure about the table of member function pointers? (For monomorphic classes.) I bet you the size of a struct does not change if you add a non-virtual member function, and it's still binary compatible with its C equivalent using the same compiler family.

Comment: @PeterSchneider You're absolutely right. A standard-layout struct can have non-virtual member functions to its heart's content, and its size/layout will not be affected.

Comment: OK, right. I was not much specific. "A Plain Old Data Structure in C++ is an aggregate class that contains only PODS as members, has no user-defined destructor..." Static functions wont' change the size, non-virtual functions -probably. I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Non-virtual non-special member functions do *not* affect a structure's state of being POD. C++14 [class]/10.

Answer (score 2):

It works because myStruct does not have a destructor. [Edit: I now see that you tried that, and it does crash. I would find the question interesting why it crashes with that dtor, since the dtor does not access any memory of the object.]

As others said, the second function of free[] besides potentially calling the elements' dtors (which doesn't happen here, as described) is to free the memory.

That works perfectly in your implementation because typically free store implementations just allocate a block of memory for that purpose whose size is kept in a book keeping location in that very memory. The size (once allocated) is type independent, i.e. is not derived from the pointer type on free. Cf. [How does delete[] "know" the size of the operand array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array). The malloc like, type agnostic allocator returns the chunk of memory and is happy.

Note that, of course, what you do is bogous and don't do that at home and don't publish it and make ppl sign non liability disagreements and don't use it in nuclear facilities and always return int from main().

Comment: _"myStruct does not have a destructor"_ Yes it does.

Comment: Not in the code presented, or am I missing something?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Hm, I assume you are refering to the automatically generated default destructor. Now that's almost an ontological question whether something that leaves no observable trace exists. We could call it explicitly, so I guess technically it exists, conceded.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `obj.U.structPtr` points to a struct, which can have a constructor and destructor.

`delete` also requires the correct type, otherwise it cannot call the destructor.

So it is illegal to create a `char` array with `new` and delete it as an `struct` pointer.

It would be okay if you use `malloc` and `free`. This won't call the constructor and destructor.