# can I query if a pointer is the first in a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays

If delete[] "knows" the size of any dynamically allocated array, shouldn't I be able to query its size somehow?

This is from cplusplus.com mixed with some of my own code to show what I mean:

```
// operator delete[] example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

struct MyClass {
  MyClass() {std::cout <<"MyClass constructed\n";}
  ~MyClass() {std::cout <<"MyClass destroyed\n";}
};

int main () {
  MyClass * pt;
  MyClass * foo;
  MyClass * bar;

  pt = new MyClass[3];
  delete[] pt;      
  foo = new MyClass[12];
  delete[] &foo[0]; // this works      
  bar = new MyClass[33];
  delete[] &bar[1]; // this does not work

  return 0;
}
```

Motivation: If the first element of the array is special than any for-all would need only the last pointer and decrement until the first is detected... (I guess it could be "found" by looking for delete[] exception/error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does delete\[\] "know" the size of the operand array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array)

Comment: Where do you initialize foo and bar? The second example you show should not work, as foo was never declared.  This does not compile.

Comment: Although this is a rather popular demand, the answer is, unfortunately, "no".

Comment: You're asking two question. The one in your question's title and in the first sentence of the question. Which question do you want answered here?

Comment: If you read the information about the tags, you would see that `dynamic-arrays` is specifically about array like constructs that can change size dynamically at runtime (and not dynamically allocated arrays).

Comment: `&foo[0]`, `foo` and `&0[foo]` are equivalent to `foo + 0`. In this case you are releasing memory using pointer to the front of memory block. With `delete[] &bar[1];` you are trying to release memory by pointer which is set to middle of allocated memory block. Standard library threats this as a fatal error of heap corruption.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris added declaration of foo and bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach - though being quite creative :-) - does not work. The reason is that you cannot "try out" `delete`; you rather have to make sure that the pointer  passed to `delete` is one that has previously been obtained by `new`. Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined (cf, for example, [this definition of delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) at cppreference.com):

> If the pointer passed to the standard library deallocation function
>   was not obtained from the corresponding standard library allocation
>   function, the behavior is undefined.

So any try that has not been "the first pointer" (i.e. the beginning of the array)  will yield undefined behaviour (a crash, something obscure, even nothing) and you must not rely on such a "behaviour".

Comment: `MyClass *pt1 = new MyClass[3];
 MyClass *pt2 = &pt1[0];
 std::cout << std::boolalpha << (pt1 == pt2);` Techically `pt2` was not obtained from the corresponding standard library allocation function, yet it is the same pointer as `pt1` that was obtained from the corresponding standard library allocation function. It this still UB?

Comment: @KillzoneKid -- by that analysis, `pt1` was not obtained from the standard library allocation function. It's value is a **copy** of the pointer that the allocation function returned. So is `pt2`. Choose your poison: either nothing works because of a hyper-technical (and unwarranted) reading of the requirement, or both of them work.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: What is important is that the memory address you pass to `delete` must be the same address that `new` returned.  How you determine the address before passing it to `delete` does not matter.  `pt1`, `&pt1[0]`, `pt1+0`, `pt1+1-1`, they all point to the same address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is what I thought and what makes sense. Just wanted to make sure cppreference formulation is not final.