# Why do we even need the delete operator? (Can't we just use delete[])

Tags: c++, pointers

I was reading about the `delete` and `delete[]` operators today and  I can see that
to free the memory allocated to `myChar`, I should call `delete` and to free memory for `myCharArray` I should use `delete[]`.

However I have always thought of `myChar` as a pointer to an array of size 1. So why is it that we use `delete` in this case; and why do we need `delete` at all? Couldn't we have gotten away with using `delete[]` everywhere if `myChar` is effectively an array of size 1?

```
char* myChar = new char;
char* myCharArray = new char[5];

delete myChar;
delete[] myCharArray;
```

Comment: I actually did look at this page; my question is why is it necessary to have both delete and delete[].

Comment: For this case, it's just `delete(myCharArray)`

Comment: `delete[]` is necessary when objects are involved. `char` is a basic datatype.

Comment: Because  every `new` should be accompanied by `delete` and every `new[]` should be accompanied by `delete[]`. In fact you should be using smart pointers instead.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. What I am trying to understand is why we don't just call delete[] on pointers that effectively point to arrays of size 1?

Comment: I can see that "using delete on a pointer returned by new [] results in undefined behavior." and I completely understand that but why don't we just have delete[] if that works for both myChar and myCharArray?

Comment: Because objects are not arrays of size 1. If you define an array,  the size of the array is stored somewhere in the memory (this is implementation defined). If you use `delete[]`, it has to know this size... But for plain pointers to objects, there is no such information...

Comment: Just because it works here in this example, doesn't mean it will always work and you can rely on it, it's undefined behavior. Imagine you have a base class with virtual destructor and derived class, and you do `Base *ptr = new Derived`, if you use `delete[] ptr`, how is the compiler supposed to know which destructor to call?

Comment: Ok, I think I see, so when I call delete[] myChar I don't get an exception thrown here, is this then an undefined operation on myChar?

Comment: Also this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array

Comment: You won't get exception here, it's undefined behavior, not an operation that may throw exceptions.

Comment: @AdaRaider Yes, it is undefined. If it appears to work, that's just bad luck.

Comment: Ok I see now, thanks all.

Comment: Reopened: this question isn't about the **difference** between `delete` and `delete[]`; it's about **why** they're different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single object is *not* an array of size 1.  An array of size 1, created with `new char[1]`, needs to record the number of objects that were allocated, so that `delete[]` knows *how many* objects to destroy.

Arguably, `new` *could* be implemented internally as `new[1]` (and `delete` implemented as `delete[]`) - that would be a correct implementation.  However, having separate `new` and `new[1]` allows the optimization of not storing the object count for single objects (a very common case).

The C++ principle of not paying for what you don't use comes into play here.  If we create an array of objects, we pay the memory and processing price of storing the count, but if we create a single object, we don't incur the overhead.

Comment: A single object **is**, in may contexts, an array of size 1. `int i = 3; int* begin = &i; int* end = &(i + 1); while (begin != end) std::cout << *begin++;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker i think it's rather effect of arrays decaying to pointers than objects being arrays of size 1.

Comment: @TobySpeight -- "in the context of `delete[]` they are different" is just restating the question.

Comment: @Pete, I've edited to make clearer that having distinct `new` and `new[]` (and their corresponding `delete` and `delete[]`) is an optimisation.  Have I captured the essence better now?

Answer (score 6):

You're right that there's no inherent reason for the distinction between `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]`; the language could have simply omitted the non-array version, or omitted `delete` and required `delete[]` to work correctly with a single object allocated by `new`. But doing that adds complexity and corresponding overhead to the implementation for the single-object case, since it would then have to store a size of 1 somewhere so that `delete[]` could do the right thing. One of the primary design principles of C++ was (and is) that you don't pay for what you don't use. `new/delete` is the result of this parsimony. It moves the cost from the implementation to the programmer.