# How to get the size of an array from over-allocated part of memory in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

I wanted to dig into how delete [] is knowing how many elements it has to erase from memory. I found [num-elems-in-new-array-overalloc](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/num-elems-in-new-array-overalloc.html) which is pretty clear.
I know the implementation is compiler-specific but I just have the problem here to get the correct size of the array from the memory. I have no direct need of this functionality, just want to understand more clearly.
As stated at [num-elems-in-new-array-overalloc](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/num-elems-in-new-array-overalloc.html) the size of an array can be stored by over-allocating memory.

```
char* tmp = (char*) operator new[] (WORDSIZE + n * sizeof(int));
```

Afterward, the pointer to the first array element is derived and the number of elements is stored at `tmp` pointer.

```
int* p = (int*) (tmp + WORDSIZE);
*(size_t*)tmp = n;
```

My assumption is here that in case of decrementing the `p` pointer two times (I assume `WORDSIZE == sizeof(size_t)` with `sizeof(size_t)== 8 Byte`) I should get the array size `n`.
I made a small example [over-allocation](https://repl.it/talk/share/delete/52829) where I try to get the array size but somehow I get 49 instead of 40 as the array size in case of 10 array elements.

```
int* tmp = arr - 2;
std::cout << "Array size: " << *tmp << std::endl;

Address 0: 0x9efe70
Address 1: 0x9efe74
Address 2: 0x9efe78
Address 3: 0x9efe7c
Address 4: 0x9efe80
Address 5: 0x9efe84
Address 6: 0x9efe88
Address 7: 0x9efe8c
Address 8: 0x9efe90
Address 9: 0x9efe94
Array size: 49 <- In question
```

Probably my assumptions about WORDSIZE or the implementation in the compiler were wrong. What am I missing? I know about [How does delete[] “know” the size of the operand array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array) but the answers are not really satisfying my question.

For those who have problems with repl.it, the full example:

```
#include <iostream>

void printMemoryLayout(int *arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Address " << i << ": " << &arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int n = 10;

int main() {
    int* arr = new int[n];

    printMemoryLayout(arr, n);
    int* tmp = arr - 2;
    std::cout << "Array size: " << *tmp << std::endl;
}
```

UPDATE:
The compiler used was clang 7.0.0.3

Comment: That's not a duplicate. At least in my understanding the question is not how `delete[]` knows the size, but why OP's implementation does not work as expected.

Comment: On that node @Ben 1980: Please provide your code as [mre] in the question. Questions should be self contained and the site you linked asks me to fill a captcha first, which is annoying. Maybe the solution is to stop guessing sizes and use `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(int)` instead.

Comment: Don't use `new` or `delete` (and the array variants) manually in your code. Use a `std::vector<>` instead.

Comment: @churill It's an XY problem stated, yes. But that doesn't make the question any better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's clear but wasn't my question

Comment: @Ben1980 _" but I just have the problem here to get the correct size of the array from the memory"_ Short answer: You can't without knowing the specific internals.

Comment: @churill yes I know ```sizeof(...)``` but I would like to know why ````*tmp``` is not showing what I was assuming it would show

Comment: To get a meanigful answer you would have to specify the compiler. I't likely that all o the major compilers do something similar, but the odds of them all being the exactly the same borders on 0. This is definitely a case where you would need to split hairs, so knowing the compiler is a must.