# Unable to dereference a pointer pointing to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have passed **pointer to a pointer** as a parameter to function and the goal is to make an array inside of that function. I have done that step properly and also inside of the function checked the **address and value* of the array(`local`) as well as **pointed** by the pointer(`op_ptr_array_`) and they are the same(as desired).

But the problem is occurring while I want to **dereference** the provided pointer(`op_ptr_array`). The values are wrong while addresses are matched with the pointed array(`local`).

My idea is that as the address of `op_ptr_array`(pointer passed to the function) is equal to the `local` and `op_ptr_array_` (array and pointer inside of the function) so using a for loop `*(op_ptr_array+i)` will provide me the result where `i < op_size`.

The approach I have taken is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

void op_calculation(unsigned int*  ip_ptr_array_,
                    unsigned int   ip_size_,
                    unsigned int** op_ptr_array_,
                    unsigned int*  op_size_)
{
    *(op_size_) = ip_size_ + 2;
    std::cout<<"op_size_ address: "<<op_size_<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"op_size_ value: "<<*(op_size_)<<std::endl;

    unsigned int local[*(op_size_)];
    std::cout<<"making local array to be pointed by op_ptr_array_\n";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i< *(op_size_); i++)
    {
        local[i]=i+1*3;
        std::cout<<local[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    *op_ptr_array_ = &local[0];
    local[3] = 87; // for checking pointer charecter
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < *(op_size_); i++)
        std::cout<<"array address: "<<&local[i]<<" ,op_ptr_array address: "<<(*op_ptr_array_)+i<<" ,val of array: "<<local[i]<<" ,val at op_ptr_array: "<<*((*op_ptr_array_)+i)<<std::endl;
        // here value and addresses are same which is desired
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int ip_size = 10;
    unsigned int* ip_ptr_array = new unsigned int[ip_size];

    unsigned int op_size;
    unsigned int* op_ptr_array;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ip_size; i++)
    {
        ip_ptr_array[i] = i+2*2;
    }

    op_calculation(ip_ptr_array,
                ip_size,
                &op_ptr_array,
                &op_size);
    
    std::cout<<"Value printing after operation of op_calculation function\n";
    std::cout<<"op_size: "<<op_size<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"op_ptr_array\n";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < op_size; i++)
        std::cout<<"Address: "<<(op_ptr_array+i)<<" , Value: "<<*(op_ptr_array+i)<<"\n";
        /* Here only addresses are same with `local array` and
        address pointed by op_ptr_array_ pointer` which you will find in op_calculation
        function but values are different*/
    std::cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea where I am making the mess is highly appreciable.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: It is a snippet of my project

Comment: `local` is local to the method, while `op_ptr_array` in `main` is just a pointer, and that pointer is invalid once the method returns

Comment: What would be the way if I want to get the value of `local` array with `op_ptr_array` in the main function?

Comment: is there a reason to not use `std::array` or `std::vector` ?

Comment: Why are you mucking around with pointers and manual memory management in the first place? Use `std::vector`. (Unless it's for practice, which is a valid reason in my book..)

Answer (score 1):

Variable `local` is being declared as a local variable (i.e. on the stack).  This falls out of scope when the function `op_calculation` exits, which means that the memory originally used to allocate `local` may be used for something else.

This can be corrected by converting `local` to a pointer and using `new` to allocate memory for the array’s contents or by declaring local as `static`, which will place the contents elsewhere in RAM.  Keep in mind, if you use `static` any future calls to `op_calculation` will overwrite the contents of the array, even if it is still in use elsewhere.  This would not be a problem if you used `new`, but if you use `new` you will need to remember to deallocate the array using `delete[]` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: What I have understood by reading your answer is that--- I have declared `local` as like as follows.


`unsigned int* local = new unsigned int[*(op_size_)];`
In this case **dereferencing** works. But my ques is in which section I will call now `delete [] local`? If I call it at the end of `op_calculation` function without any doubt it will cause error.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Sorry, I mentioned `malloc` in the answer, but you are in C++ so you would use `new`.  You will no longer have access to `local` once `op_calculation ` exits, but you can deallocate using `delete[] op_ptr_array;`  The `delete[]` keyword operates on a pointer to an array and will deallocate whatever is being pointed to.

Comment: But, I have declared `unsigned int* op_ptr_array;`. Can I do `delete [] op_ptr_array;` for this? I am not sure the declaration is here dynamically allocated memory or not(As far I have read `delete` operator I can use if I declare anything with `new`). Maybe I can use `delete op_ptr_array;`(without square braces). Though both have compiled without error but don't understand what is the correct logic/ process to follow.

Comment: The pointer stored in `op_ptr_array` would have been created by `new`, which is what will be used by the `delete[]` operator to deallocate when you use delete on `op_ptr_array`.  There is a little bit of detail on how `delete[]` works here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array.

Comment: ok, now I have understood.

so, if I say,`op_ptr_array` is pointing to `op_ptr_array_` and `op_ptr_array_` is pointing to `local`, is it correct?

Besides, Now I have an issue while I execute the binary with `valgrind`. Still, it cannot free all heap memory (`still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks`).

Comment: Basically yes.  You would allocate local with new `unsigned int* local = new unsigned int[*(op_size_)];`  inside of the function.  Then assign it to `op_ptr_array` when you dereference parameter `op_ptr_array_` in statement ` *op_ptr_array_ = &local[0]; ` inside of the function.  So the pointer will then be stored in `opt_ptr_array` when the function returns to `main`.  As a side note, you could replace `&local[0]` with `local`, as they are effectively the same thing.

Comment: Can you kindly take a look [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa8ffa22978da139)? It is throwing me a `memory leak error` while executing the binary by `valgrind ./main`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236738/discussion-between-jonathon-s-and-user10634362).